# Nested keyof object paths (using dot notation)

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for nested object paths: Is something like this possible?

```
interface IHuman {
    age: number;
    friend: {
        name: string;
    }
}

keyof IHuman; // "age", "friend.name"
```

Comment: Not at compile time, no...

Comment: I've closed this question because it's out of date; newer answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object).

Answer (score 3):

#### v1 - dot path

```
interface Obj {
  a: {
    x: string
    y: {
      z: string
    }
  }
  b: {
    u: boolean
  }
  c: number
}

type D = DotBranch<Obj> // type D = "c" | "a.x" | "a.y.z" | "b.u"

declare function get(path: DotBranch<Obj>)
get('') // Argument of type '""' is not assignable to parameter of type '"c" | "a.x" | "a.y.z" | "b.u"'.
```

```
type DotJoin<A extends string, B extends string> = A extends '' ? B : `${A}.${B}`

type DeepKeys<O extends AnyObject> = {
  [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends AnyObject ? K : never
}[keyof O]

// @ts-expect-error Type 'keyof O' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
type DotBranch<O extends AnyObject, P extends string = '', K extends string = keyof O> =
  K extends DeepKeys<O>
  ? DotBranch<O[K], DotJoin<P, K>>
  : /*************/ DotJoin<P, K>

type AnyObject = Record<string, any>
```

#### v2 - infer values

*See linked gist or playground v2 below to peek under the hood and **copy the code.***

```
type DotType<O extends AnyObject, T extends string & DotBranch<O>> = T extends `${infer A}.${infer B}`
  // @ts-expect-error B of type string is not assignable to the constraint
  ? DotType<O[A], B>
  : O[T]

const obj = {
  a: {
    x: 'xx',
    y: {
      z: 'zz',
    },
  },
  b: {
    u: true,
  },
  c: 42,
} as const

type V = DotType<typeof obj, 'c'> // type V = 42 

declare function get<P extends DotBranch<Obj>>(path: P): DotType<Obj, P>

const leaf = getLeaf('a.y.z') // leaf: 'zz'
```

[GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/ackvf/de21847e78083034252961d550963579#file-deep-object-dot-path-ts)
[Typescript Playground v2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAsAKBjAhgFwY555EwDaA5PtQDQzXzUC69pZAHsdV1w054AnsSy4yeAF68pUwRLwBfDhJWd4YoTACuxKACcdAU1XKzMYMQAsAJlVKCES+GgwA9O5gAeALQwoAAsAS2dQmGCAWwAHEAMofDBYADM4gOFo4xgAMhgAN3wAGxMIsGTjA2MwYGMcHGCkiuT8GpgAeQAhACkSCQpxSQpoAwaAc0pWbR4YYbHtUV7JaWJZsFHtJU5NiU1Fsj0YeBAQQuNErc4rGDAdSPgKnG267BxPGF8Pz6-vn9+--4BgKBwJBQNeXkAvBuAcR2YAAFQr4YQwADuwSCARCzlBv2eUAyWQa5QMADUiiZnGhDCU3hDABI7EMAuzu6CBZArFLIAAzxmRAyTgSA5ARApSJhxA6O5WVybJMjDSkpgHM6XUFUGF4EKSMJFXSmQgOAVbSQqBFFVJ7Ocxi4UCqABNnFSsgB+XXGXn85DEZUwZ4G-EwAAiAEYTQHxR0DIlgIFvEbEIxmoUWQA+DxeABEwHTMAAPjB0-gAHRcbN5guF4SFqSl-PwQs6dN+zKB2yh8OR6oxuOppZ4N4Fmvp+CDrO5-NFktj8vCQdFyvVqd1htNrIAJRDaDDUAAKvjY0hGMHkyuYKvW5vxbvMvv40w6MeXthbcZgAjKjBkjpqlBguAYKNjCgbxYRgK0bTAe1A3bKMuyQZNkwACmifAgmIWEAEpiC3K9jBvRhYVTN5t0xCJnAgQI4iCRJbQ-NJqDAEBn2oHBn1ffB30-b9fzAf9AIAOUY3CQLAu1nC3CMYLwpgGKY+CkJQwI0MwqCdz3ON8IfVi3yyTjgB-P8AKgAAZM5kmA0DrVElSJM7KTqFOfBkmoOTkNQuFlOwtSDzhB8cFASBYDZPA0EMhDaELOh0L81xYBkrIQv4wSwuoKLsH8twHL5BLjNM5LUvBd5-AhQABHYhQAxHcKn4YEZcqAgMJFAgqUwMXCVqoAK7FOq67qet6n5fUfIjGpUmAcMqvqJsmqacUfBUty6EAGm8ABBCzwMg1ZRkYDo1qszbUzQVaRIg5xqGoGAXR24gOQAEnQZalELO6OiUDlcX9WERkiNFgjyYwAGljGECBY12k6YGWsBhDjF8oAOvZKH+0oYAAayB902lYL1EdYMHIMh6GkFhi7rmMP6DBgYh-seSg0eEDHJlm-0A2MYxokB4HQeO-GoZhvT4YGKgkYaVH0b5THsf+3HuecAm+dgF02hxvHnEqfBbQ1JFEmECYSbAMmKipynSfJmm6YZgbez7LwiphbdjDcIJwk67RJAVWEkbQT6oh+v6OZB7trfzLNXbIObPcDVn2aBgO4Kt-t8EHYdnit10YGJDd2iQSgAyl0O8AVYlzxgABVMBuO3EAAElGgMFk9O47wM4fVPC4AZlDKP-ab2we17fsZ3ztNxumj4Brm6DbLaFWId5om9MYABZQSZ6OE4zh4vN6ME86t8y87KSMYwDs4Zfnxnx0x23pjtBdcSO2jATn1jFuyCwyfoxMxyX8t+Obequ2DtYBOyxNiIeCojIAAY2xQBstGG8fd+4ZkTouEcs5izoJnFOOcVYk71mzMPPwMwKLxECNRWiFN76SXUtJHer9ewQMzlQqe3lr7GGcsPAcqCpyjjLBOTBmDcGLnwUHIhIDSIEEKIUGAsQIAQGCPAU4oskSuUCPqRQSwIHF2YfAmh9lTIcP7Lw8cGDsEViEWWJcBDU42LIG8IhmsYCZWUTIhSzh5JBAdGQ2AGswDUFikAj8OhSEVFSq3f0RkO4XlgQ-WCt5HR9zeAAZXwJELI+BTpxWYhot2ETrAwLgXEhMRQUxBxSWkpwTB95DzeKPb4A03gAAEoAQF8FaTIek2kGAMGkMa1Bzbi3OhrB21xxQzBQqEZISIghZHSoYfADRYDUE2tQQsJ4dGBCfrhaeMtZ6E0QLDfCM9NomjOowJGuyTloAGe0E+EgLmWXBizNm3c2ivzvh-TZglYw40POKBaS1YTnPgmOeai0wDAWBZwd+UAAUQqBTAf6vlsBNJaW0rgHSoBdJ6RTPpNy2hDJACMhisAIATIgFMjEsyYqRkWUwFZazsATxiTBL+ZkdmPJ5vsw5cJjmGDGKchgiK+UjDWCafFdy8APPWmJLuMcf4SA+SyzsbKflSz+bC8FkLEXwWhSpOF2qkXvWbJ5a8HKZV7PlowbcIqBW5A2S-SVo0Z63XQNqCmD0npurKDqF6b0JCotae02G2K0g7XdAqE54QSVOHkaMMA+BFFZDVFSlwAVaVJE4EqnCPzlrsBgB0V+2NtyMxTn-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-00OgNlfh4jxgyOcfACR7aFH49mbiiSXNtEYWIsurupZz1NOfUUz9Z1ygy10sZa3GTwoFPC29eNpQEt-3RqQLHSpTnFOb2o7PZAjd0SxdAXCm+oLkCABsMC5feAV4WYAhZCfJiAA)   *[v1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgSwDYB4YD4oF5ZQgD2AgDsATAZygG0FiAzCAJygH0AxBR84ASSIFsANFAB0Y2g2YAlCNwC6UAPxQZ3KAC4oxCADcmAWABQRo6EhQAIgHtgAWSYBzCCgCCeQiQpRujWg6pymDjwyK7oVADkSCQOwAAWEQoERGSUAAxGUEpQLlRpcplQAPRFUAACwOQAtASQAMbANYyMVsww4NAR1naOEDAArmDRaIioLujoEVAIlMQ2UHDk5AgOxHAARtFQwFbbHVARPn5QAD5a-fzrTKdQ6yu0wDfrVlbRcMQRIoWaAAYAJABvXL5AC%20IkB3XsjCcI1C43QIJ%20JkMZmgMDSAEZsJYbFCYZE4Il0KZ9uiAEzYyG9FAEiLCCLrIkk8zogDMlNx1Np9MZ9LqdIOpCZxhFqJxwAAykMEMA0EFcMlPJR-gCJNcXGDAWrmAAhRGFZRUFzCMQibpSpAylA69AFQxZTRUGB25lotIAFg5kulsoihOJKNJaQArF6LVa-SJGQGxeiAGxhn0oSPrER1ERCgPIkpQKp5-MFwtF4sl0tl8sVytVivIowPJh0OB1aAAeXWACsoADCnBNN37VkoPhNEdiA5ClkQH2J4OAF4j4C%20MczkGFVcD9bTgdZfqaZ6vCDvNeFOqaYgXK6MIzr5FilzEEBt9sQBrYmR1VqkFCjhzCd4gLNA3MboACkrFoVx3BSLwf2EHUoKVbxFz8eU3EVVIDimZR4N%20QENXBAE9SRUV9gABV8fgZQQPQAGkIBAcgUBbBCMPvR8OxfYB5X7LIqBo6ZiCgABreirDoKAWzkTQWz4pIPFYh8n047JtD0ZhNBo68qBEkAxIkl0gOgCwIAgMA6IYpiWK8NilIabjCj4gThNE8TJOk2SrMoGyONfZR%20LPXQDEMEFtJc-TbzI-icHIhBKOAaiIHMxin0wHMACI6jS11LCiywTLM%20jko7VLSjSuA0puNL1iykjgKxHAnyoCwaIM7Luh1Rh3jqOJLPQ6zFJ84BhFIzykKXBxsQiAV%20L6ygf2xHS9JbIJChm%20SvGM0ykqYgMsmUdrOuIbqmNk4RQPA4gUFI4QaImb5igAKie56Xue0pzog66oFuiLgK9Dqup6lLilKMULGxDKKrOMqRHwKGoBhkARFneGqpEfoaqMUgXyQOBGGgOh%20iO%20KrEEpxgAACjAOB4k0A7AaY4qAEojHJimpqZkGcmhC4SEePSxQiNK0qmGYtHmRZllWDYth2KBqc6-gICIZgBf2IXMsquBYdR7WkZRyrUwxz4KbJVl3WDFnDCAA)*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, as for why i can make a wild guess:

```
interface IHuman {
    age: number;
    'friend.name': any;
    friend: {
        name: string;
    }
}

const b: keyof IHuman = 'friend.name';
```

`friend.name` would now be ambigious.

Comment: If there are two leafs with the same path, it would be possible to return a conjunction of both types `A | B`. It would then be up to the actual implementation to choose which one to return.

Answer (score 1):

I've not found a nice solution for this too. 
But you might want to take a look at *[typed-path](https://github.com/bsalex/typed-path)* project.

[image: The main idea of this project in a single image]

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible because there are no [string literal type operators](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12940) in TypeScript. Given the string literals `"foo"` and `"bar"`, there is no programmatic way to get the string literal `"foo.bar"` from the type systm.  There are several feature suggestions filed in GitHub which might, if implemented, make this possible, like [key augmentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) or [regular-expression string validation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579).  But it doesn't look like they are being actively worked on.

Comment: Just a heads up that it is now possible https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336