# Multi Level Index Type Typescript

Tags: typescript

Hi all I'm wondering if somebody could help me.

I have a function that takes each level of an object as a string with a dot seperator

eg

```
const fooType = {
  test: {
    test1: {
      test2: 'test'
    }
  },
  testing: {
    testable: 'be'
  },
  bottom: 'b'
};
```

so if I wanted to get the value of test2 I would write the function as

`foo('test.test1.test2')`

if I take the following `type fooTypeProps = keyof typeof fooType;`

It gives me a union of `test | testing | bottom`

I'm wondering if there is a way in typescript to get that keyof but for all the layors so In this situation I would have a union of `test.test1.test2 | testing.testable | bottom`

Comment: There's no type-level string manipulation so the compiler cannot turn `"test"` and `"test1"` into `"test.test1"`.  The best you can get is tuples like `["test", "test1", "test2"] | ["testing", "testable"] | ["bottom"]`

Answer (score 0):

In the [question this duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object) you can take your type and get a union of tuples representing the leaves of the tree of paths:

```
type AllLeaves = Leaves<typeof fooType>
/* type AllLeaves = ["test", "test1", "test2"] | ["testing", "testable"] | ["bottom"] */
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM4B4ASAaKAVAfFAXhyggA9gIEATJKAJwgEMrEAbEKRhEAbQF0oAfgCwAKCgSoACikALAFxRMUAHRrgi7AEpC+AG5wAllR1kK1WjLUq6iwwgBmEOlABKOgvqMmhbqIoQIPWcxSX8oQOC6AG4xMVBIKAAFBj1CKB5I5ywABiwARiwAJiwAZiwAFiwAViwANiwAdiwADiwATgK80Ml8wqh8koHygaqB2oGGgeaBtoHOqCK81TUc-j440QToJMZgWVRsLAAREnJKGgiAVwBbACNndPyc-CIeY4EzC9pMoOcBQQRP4uTRncyXOB3ABWEAAxsAhD0JABvDIAaSg9igAGsICA4A4cHwALSCRTwZAoNFYXb7Q48NF8Gmpd58XD4AA+yT2BxQ2AZTOSLI++AAvjxcfjCdgNuJJIp+LFRPFwNAADJMYKHE5g77Xe6PIjPV4ZD66iwZLJ0AFAqLhbDmiHQuEIkRylHozEIHF4glE0nkxCoalQDWMLV8gXMoKs9lQcWSv0ypHhRWbWFBhEOOBwbCq9LInoUJAaKCF91QYvAfKKVEpiRVoqKADkVebKdFPVFGCLEBL9gA5rWU1XGHdWBAWw923Luz07nBgMA4DcpzPRdEoJttlAAIKsVhhrXpI99lDbP3Z3Oq3BiAD0ACpK-n94fNX30jwAERVr9YH99tWf5QABJZFF+Ahct+VaDsBoHAGOE4QVAUFfguS4rshD53kAA)

But you can't convert those into dotted strings in the type system, which has no notion of string literal manipulation.