# TypeScript type definition for an object property path

Tags: typescript, recursion, reflection, types, jsonpointer

Is it possible to type an array of strings in such a way that the array can only be a valid property path in a given object? The type definition should work for all deeply nested objects.

Example:

```
const object1 = {
    someProperty: true
};
const object2 = {
    nestedObject: object1,
    anotherProperty: 2
};

type PropertyPath<Type extends object> = [keyof Type, ...Array<string>]; // <-- this needs to be improved

// ----------------------------------------------------------------

let propertyPath1: PropertyPath<typeof object1>;

propertyPath1 = ["someProperty"]; // works
propertyPath1 = ["doesntExist"]; // should not work

let propertyPath2: PropertyPath<typeof object2>;

propertyPath2 = ["nestedObject", "someProperty"]; // works
propertyPath2 = ["nestedObject", "doesntExist"]; // should not work
propertyPath2 = ["doesntExist"]; // should not work
```

[Link to TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=52#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArApsKBGGBeGBvAUDETBCALbIAKATiAA7LVQCeAXDFNQK7L4C%20AbnyhIsBCjQAmbHkLEwyaMgAmAeSSoo7cZvQAaOUQCGYEFAAWjGvUYt2k-kPwsGMawybNKRiwB4AKsyuyAAeUMhgyhBwGmgAfDIA2gDWyMwgAGYwgQx6MAB0hQCC1NRGzL7Q1ACWYADmcQC6AjAA9K0wvgC0XRzm1dEKKtFQIDDwyDDVZHS0AG4q%20PjtMD1r6xubW9s7u7tLADbIsLM2nt4W6Ozutl4%205r4uyJkxEhhxTqceLBfmmDiJABEpAoN08gOabQ6AHcQNRkhB8F9br9-jAgcoQIowFAAKIhAZQCEtFYQcwgLgHZQwUywWHww7HGDI873STXWjfO5%20J4vHRSD5LFk-NlJQEKJRqWJEvLA8hUTm3YlQmD0hFIxWsizSAHixThKVvQGyzHYvEE6DK0nkynU2mquHJDVnEXasWmiA4-GEq0dMkUqk0swO%20FAA)

Comment: I don't really understand the "should work for all deeply nested objects.", because that seems impossible. You can however make the type: `type PropertyPath<Type extends object> = (keyof Type)[];`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In [the answer to the question this duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436959/2887218) you can use the recursive `Paths<>` or `Leaves<>` type aliases, depending on whether or not you want to support all paths that start at the root and end anywhere in the tree (`Paths<>`) or if you want to only support paths that start at the root and end at the leaves of the tree (`Leaves<>`):

```
type AllPathsObject2 = Paths<typeof object2>;
// type AllPathsObject2 = ["nestedObject"] | ["nestedObject", "someProperty"] | 
//  ["anotherProperty"]

type LeavesObject2 = Leaves<typeof object2>;
// type LeavesObject2 = ["nestedObject", "someProperty"] | ["anotherProperty"]
```

I'll assume it's `Paths` but you can change it to `Leaves` if that fits your use case.  Here's the behavior you get, which matches what you asked for:

```
let propertyPath1: Paths<typeof object1>;
propertyPath1 = ["someProperty"]; // works
propertyPath1 = ["doesntExist"]; // error!
//               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

let propertyPath2: Paths<typeof object2>;
propertyPath2 = ["nestedObject", "someProperty"]; // works
propertyPath2 = ["nestedObject", "doesntExist"]; // error!
//                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
propertyPath2 = ["doesntExist"]; // error!
//               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM4B4ASAaKAVAfFAXhyggA9gIEATJKAJwgEMrEAbEKRhEAbQF0oAfgCwAKCgSoACikALAFxRMUAHRrgi7AEpC+AG5wAllR1kK1WjLUq6iwwgBmEOlABKOgvqMmhbqIoQIPWcxSX8oQOC6AG4xMVBIKAAFBj1CKB5I5ywABiwARiwAJiwAZiwAFiwAViwANiwAdiwADiwATgK80Ml8wqh8koHygaqB2oGGgeaBtoHOqCK81TUc-j440QToJMZgWVRsLAAREnJKGgiAVwBbACNndPyc-CIeY4EzC9pMoOcBQQRP4uTRncyXOB3ABWEAAxsAhD0JABvDIAaSg9igAGsICA4A4cHwALSCRQ8NECAA+0l2+0OFL4WBSQXefHwXwsmMcjySiPEYUkfM5l34viyINgiFQaOZ+ACwKRUB0AF8eLj8YTsBsBRJyXxYqJ4uBoAAZJjBQ4nMHfa73R5EZ6vDIfG1c35RAFAqLhbBuiHQuEIkS6qCoincnF4glE0mKeDIFCyqDmxiWlDYRnM1Js3D4NUamPapX6w2hMSw6UIyEw+H5dLIpVIOA3CApOCQOigRTAOhXCBiFVl0SV5DVwPwooNpWBJAUKgAeQnGigNaDhSVXDg+2c7c73cWg+H2ygAEFWKw6Qcl7XgFOiFfUNsY2vJ7hDQB6D9QE-ny97a9l3vDIACJZ3nG8gxA6lQPAiBF2XECsBA5tWz3ZxQGgqAaTEL8JB4ECtx3Oh0K7EBoONRJU0tSDJ3SaiICfE0XyA99cO-E8GKQWi73SAi4IQ28kKgFCWzbOgOww8iYIIojZF3CT92kzZWAgBEwEUqSr3yRRHxQZ9CVfYB8jY0QNMksjtL40S0M0sjoOiKA8IAdzgOhsSQMRzKUqy3hAlhGIQYAAFFSEMOcHKc79nAkugAEJ2MFJKwgAPzS9KMoyzYxFU9S7NAK8il0gCmMgFjbyKUzvK0gDgP4xiIMQ5DUPEizMINKKoFc9zPLM-KQEK6yBJ44T-LgQKQrCiKOrwmK3IS0Q8OS5aVqSzL1rSrz+sGvyAqQILQvC4BItmuhYoWpbVskDb1uyo1RCAA)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! `Paths` is what I was looking for. This is this kind of type you never want to have in your codebase and you're happy someone else did it for you :D

Comment: This  is probably the most serious Typescript voodoo I've ever seen. Nice!

Comment: Is there any better solution to access the keys using the same data which is in the array without joining them

Comment: @Shivam I don't understand the question, sorry.

Comment: @jcalz what I meant was instead of accessing or defining them within arrays ["someProp"] then accessing the object key value with array[0], how can we just use the path as string eg "someProp" ?

Comment: Are you asking for a special case for tuples of length one? If not, what do you want to see for nested properties?  Also note that comments on year-old questions aren’t necessarily the best place to get followup answers.

Comment: This is great, thank you! Is there a way to get the type of the value too? E.g.


```function setByPath<Obj, Key extends Paths[Obj]>(obj: Obj, path: Key, value: ???<Obj, Key>) { }```

Comment: UPD to my prev comment: I think I found an answer, link: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-sznv9i

Answer (score -5):

It's possible using arrow functions

```
const object1 = {
    someProperty: true
};
const object2 = {
    nestedObject: object1,
    anotherProperty: 2
};

type PropertyPath<Type extends object> = (x: Type) => any;

let propertyPath1: PropertyPath<typeof object1>;

propertyPath1 = (x) => x.someProperty; // works
propertyPath1 = (x) => x.doesntExist; // should not work

let propertyPath2: PropertyPath<typeof object2>;

propertyPath2 = (x) => x.nestedObject.someProperty; // works
propertyPath2 = (x) => x.nestedObject.doesntExist; // should not work
propertyPath2 = (x) => x.doesntExist; // should not work
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=57#)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I was asking for