# dynamic Optional.fromPath

Tags: typescript, lenses, fp-ts, monocle-ts

Can i access nested properties with monocle-ts in a dynamic fashion?

The closest i can find directly from the library is the Optional.fromPath, combined with a dynamic path. Based on the [example from the documentation](https://gcanti.github.io/monocle-ts/modules/index.ts.html#frompath-static-method-1) for fromPath we can create a small utility function for that specific parent object. However, then you need to type the path.

There is a way to [recursively create path types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59455679/typescript-type-definition-for-an-object-property-path) from an object type. However, this also leads to an error.

```js
const responsePath = (path: Paths<Reponse>) => Optional.fromPath<Response>()(path);
// type ["info", "employment"] is not assignable to type "info"
```

Code for creating a path type:

```
    type Cons<H, T> = T extends readonly any[] ?
    ((h: H, ...t: T) => void) extends ((...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never
    : never;

    type Prev = [never, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
        11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...0[]]
    
    type Paths<T, D extends number = 10> = [D] extends [never] ? never : T extends object ?
        { [K in keyof T]-?: [K] | (Paths<T[K], Prev[D]> extends infer P ?
            P extends [] ? never : Cons<K, P> : never
        ) }[keyof T]
        : [];
```

Summary: Optional.fromPath doesn't work out of the box to dynamically select paths. Is there a way to create a function like the above "responsePath" with Optional.fromPath or other methods from monocle-ts?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, unfortunately. [`OptionalFromPath`](https://github.com/gcanti/monocle-ts/blob/213e9b192a3572a1baa7243adb4455bb7a0439e5/src/index.ts#L754-L784=) hard codes overloads for up to 5 paths, but doesn't have an overload for the general case of any array of paths.