# Collapse nested keys in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Say I have two types in TypeScript:

```
interface Foo {
  bar: string;
}

interface Baz {
  foo: Foo;
}
```

Is there a way in TypeScript to flatten `Baz` (e.g. `type FlatBaz = Flat<Baz>`), such that the signature looks something like this?

```
interface FlatBaz {
  "foo.bar": string;
}
```

Comment: I'd be interested to know what you're trying to achieve. because your `FlatBaz` type looks like it would be the structure of a type returned from some function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: deep keyof of a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object)

Comment: @DamianGreen yes - it would be returned from a function. I'm mapping objects to/from query parameters and would like to more strongly type the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Currently there is no way to concat string literal types with Typescript:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no such a thing.