# Define a function return value as a type of reading a path in object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I would like to create a simple helper function to read a path from an object like this:

```
interface Human {
  address: {
    city: {
      name: string;
    }
  }
}

const human: Human = { address: { city: { name: "Town"}}};
getIn<Human>(human, "address.city.name"); // Returns "Town"
```

This helper is easy to create in JS, but making it type safe in TS is a bit more complicated. I have got this far:

```
type Prev = [never, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...0[]];

type Join<K, P> = K extends string | number
  ? P extends string | number
    ? `${K}${"" extends P ? "" : "."}${P}`
    : never
  : never;

type Path<T, D extends number = 4> = [D] extends [never]
  ? never
  : T extends object
  ? {
      [K in keyof T]-?: K extends string | number
        ? `${K}` | Join<K, Path<T[K], Prev[D]>>
        : never;
    }[keyof T]
  : "";

function getIn<T extends Record<string, any>>(object: T, path: Path<T>): T {
  const parts = path.split(".");
  return parts.reduce<T>((result, key) => {
    if (result !== undefined && result[key]) {
      return result[key];
    }

    return undefined;
  }, object);
}
```

This works, but what is wrong here is that the return type of `getIn` should not be `T`, but something inside `T`, depending on the given path. So if called like this:

```
getIn<Human>(human, "address.city.name"); // Returns "Town"
```

TypeScript should know that the return value is a string, as defined in the `Human` interface. If given `"address.city"`, the return type should be `City` etc.

Is there any way to make it type safe?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wE4RkW) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Wow, awesome! This looks exactly what I need. What a wonderful TypeScript master you are. :)

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm mostly going to be concerned with getting the typings right for the call signature of `getIn()`.  It'll be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) call signature involving [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) that use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to parse and manipulate string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  There's no way for the compiler to verify that the return value will be assignable to such a complicated type, so the implementation is going to need one or more [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to avoid errors.  All this means: take care when implementing the function to make sure you're doing it right; the compiler won't catch a mistake because you're going to throw `as any` in there with abandon until it compiles.

Here's the basic plan:

```
declare function getIn<T extends object, K extends ValidatePath<T, K>>(
  object: T,
  path: K
): DeepIdx<T, K>;
```

The idea is that we will define two utility types:

- `ValidatePath<T, K>` will take an object type `T` and a string type `K` representing a dotted path to a property of `T`.  If `K` is a *valid* path for `T`, then `ValidatePath<T, K>` will be equivalent to `K`.  If it is an *invalid* path for `T`, then `ValidatePath<T, K>` will be some valid path which is "close" to `K`, for some definition of "close".  The hope is that we could [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `K extends ValidatePath<T, K>` so that valid paths will be accepted, and invalid paths will generate an error message that suggests a valid path.
- `DeepIdx<T, K>` will take an object type `T` and a string type `K` representing a dotted path to a property of `T`, and then `DeepIdx<T, K>` will be the type of the property of `T` at path `K`.

Before we define those, we have to fix the call signature.  The compiler will almost certainly complain that `K extends ValidatePath<T, K>` is an invalid circular constraint.  We can work around that by only constraining `K` to `string` and then writing a (fairly ugly) conditional type for the `path` parameter which will evaluate to the desired `ValidatePath<T, K>`. It looks like this:

```
declare function getIn<T extends object, K extends string>(
  object: T,
  path: K extends ValidatePath<T, K> ? K : ValidatePath<T, K>
): DeepIdx<T, K>;
```

---

Okay, now for the implementations:

```
type ValidatePath<T, K extends string> =
  K extends keyof T ? K :
  K extends `${infer K0}.${infer KR}` ?
  K0 extends keyof T ? `${K0}.${ValidatePath<T[K0], KR>}` : Extract<keyof T, string>
  : Extract<keyof T, string>

type DeepIdx<T, K extends string> =
  K extends keyof T ? T[K] :
  K extends `${infer K0}.${infer KR}` ?
  K0 extends keyof T ? DeepIdx<T[K0], KR> : never
  : never
```

In both cases, we walk through `K`.  If `K` is a key of `T`, then it's a valid path, and we're looking at the `T[K]` property.  If `K` is a dotted path, then we look at the part `K0` before the first dot.  If that is a key of `T`, then the first part is a valid path, and we need to recurse into `T[K0]` with a path of the part `KR` after the first dot.  If `K0` is *not* a key of `T`, then we have an invalid path, and so `Extract<keyof T, string>` is the "close" valid path (using [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to discard any non-string keys).  And if `K`  is neither a key of `T` nor a dotted path, then it's invalid, an so `Extract<keyof T, string>` is the "close" valid path also.

---

All right, let's test it out:

```
const human: Human = { address: { city: { name: "Town" } } };
const addr = getIn(human, "address");
// const addr: { city: { name: string; }; }
console.log(addr) // {city: {name: "Town"}}
const city = getIn(human, "address.city");
// const city: { name: string; }
console.log(city) // {name: "Town"}
const town = getIn(human, "address.city.name");
// const town: string
console.log(town) // "Town"

getIn(human, "address.city.neam"); // error!
// Argument of type '"address.city.neam"' is not 
// assignable to parameter of type '"address.city.name"'

getIn(human, ""); // error!
// Argument of type '""' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type '"address"'

getIn({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, "z") // error!
// Argument of type '"z"' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type '"a" | "b" | "c"'.
```

Looks good.  All the valid paths are accepted, and the output type is correct.  Meanwhile the invalid paths all generate errors which make a suggestion about what the correct path should have been.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQHMCmcCSUA8AKqpgB5yZQAmAzqkgEYBWm8ANKgNInmW2o04AJwRR0APgAUoVPWas4ALlSE2M1AAcAhnAAWy7mQrU6ANS0AbBFR2YACjt1EOncagD8XVMvNWbFBz1nLnFQAEplABFMTA0cKlJg11QAb3UYFEFNLSE4OgBebL0AOhoNKzhJACJiqrCAbnUhbAghNG1cmmLmqggYTElJZpoICyVULSgATw4Aa0wpsNR8tzSQWVkEMFQhzBGx1ABCfMLoKkwwUUwqVAAyW9Rh0bgAbXmpgF0ltY2N5rhWmgnmM3gsPo11hsAL6gdSyf6A1BnC5XKgQ2RQjiMFjwJZaOiTKYQmEgWEgOBTDSYVDRWLxRKqLxGPh0QQiMRufLqQy8Eyod5IbbETyEF6cD7ebk8Yz8AAGABIUqIwJghFwAAxQ4qK5WqrgAJShso83PV0pZ-IWgpUHhpMTiCSIYvVHxc+rcyigmAAbqr1J6fX7SeTKdTfNZbIEnIyeTLWcJRBJllLmXyBULbdxFCneXKdVAVWrOJrtUqC3rOIbje5Tea01aM54FSli1rFeH-PZHE7i66DeIjd5UABRchCLTwfDplQcNmJ0KQ5Sj4QTuBThszgQJjlk3cgUQUIRgCfUgASEAAtpNUuotFQqMMaMofhsYAgKc+4RsoFoL5hlHOYjotC6gkiSoAZFAWS6JekzKOeV5oIUKQTPej7Pqgb4fqkqA-n+yhVIQSAAO5QFUqBQhRFEQpBWR3g+ywYNgeCSDBiEcFU9GPnUEIAPS8ZhmRwKhD4YVhUwYXh-5buy6D1NRFEQZkSAWJgxQWEg6CSFxSz8ak4nPlJBFEaRVRQiStHCeJjFYLgUCsbBUAcVxexdOJPGgHplmYe+Ek4UZMmJvJFnKap6maZI4m6QJKQBYRJFkSFUHCXACU2cx9lsZMzloa5xTicUUkeSAXlCagqWkQB27oEpUEqWpGlaRVUDRag8WmWStksVlTltS5NBub5hWYL+PGoHpqpCEgQiHJ5AkAIJCOgl6UMJ1oUlSqAAOScblA35UNXqjVtqAIHQUBIMJc0TANCDoD+DCqeVSDZOOf6HvQ2wbdSO39YNFKFb+mBVFtnUZQ57FtWNE1CFNM3XYty1-lAa1faG21VCDp3nZdN00HdD1PalqDXR0QMfet6O-XtNAg2DdmSChWjKAAjBwDDKAATBwMDKAAzBRHEAF51ONAmTdNs0lQtS0rSjn3lVTVQiydZ24bj+L4-dWiPdSxOkzk5N6pTm2-eRAA+bUMBbbUwCDxSgEAA)