# Get union of all dotted object paths to properties of a particular type

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have an object representing dom tree visibility

```
const visibilities = {
    food: {
        visible: true,
        fruit: {
            visible: true,
            apple: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        snack: {visible: false}
    }
}
```

I want to get the visibility of apple by using a util function

```
getVisibilities(visibilities, 'food.fruit.apple')
```

but I don't know how to type the second argument.
I tried to connect keys when visibilities[K] is type of {visibility: boolean}

```
type VisibilityString<Prop extends {[key: string]: any}> = {[K in keyof Prop]: Prop[K] 
   extends {visible: boolean} ? K 
     extends string ? K | `${K}.${VisibilityArray<Prop[K]>}`: never : never}[keyof Prop]
```

got TypeError: VisibilityArray<Prop[K]> is not a string

Changing the second argument to array works but typescript still gives error in version 4.4.4

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgSwggRggNgqCCmEYC8MA3gFAwUwBmIIAJgFwnmWuLIro5NQBOArjgA0LVhSoCsTMmNnwkqLjwHDRcigEMADlqXN169ou7UN6CDjXqAvlcrWR6iGA3AA1tKOcTVMxdustrakoJCwSACCOlwAagrehPIcGFi4EAB0NPTpXlwwAGT5Sagp2HiZtHSZklA58XmFxWiYZRlZVRL8WOnaujh1HFykpFAAnlo4MAAKvCBaicQA2m44o0zQvAhgAOYAup71Jii0XBpg1rZjEzBxyS2jEby8GqMAPDNzMDgAHlA4YHR8EsVmsYBstnsmGdRtYAHwLRYAaRgWxgIJAVGmsy0+yxcyRuy+v3+gJIuSOJxwZ2sMAA-DACTAAD4M5FCGDpTm3Er3R7PN4fLQE2GEphgHBwHC8azLVYYvE4kLgaAwK44P4qojEGkafDc5pYB5PF6vNXyrylNKw0hUfhgYDYcAwbbq-VcV4AFSJfwBQNloPBO1xxHJTGOIFO5zhAAotNiIEwPey43MmPrSkb+Z7YQBKGSULiwYD8J7-KAAZVAEyhYFGiRTWggAG41Lx1SWwDAG+kJVLRtGQYR4fnZKEVeTEsXS2AK1WcP7drSBsYW+op22Z5W5pMiOuy1uJgvV3I21AO00hoEc6RgmqbvEM+W+BD3tjvSS-SD1s+gzWYfCtSRFFO3RTFBVxQVGR+H1SRDQ4w0pak6RgZFoI-MEf22ZDkRZAADAASYhEWsdJCPTXljQFbFhWsXCKDFXteBgBjJWlf15XApUwlVcZ1TwKAAEYFh1PUH3uJ9Nh2U1ePNMTUjwa1bXtR1OxdKA3RwATPXfX0SH9b9JMhMl4JgcNIwuWFY3jRNk3jTC0zksYJJfD1cxHGAx1gBs+Rees7MM9IIF0LBowAcnSUKc2PChCw8ksN1nbc-z8uZm1bdteE7bzKJ7Vj+0HAhhzsChPIvHc4unRLDxBRdl28aKxD3Tc50neL9znI9ipgU9z3JNRrGvG8uIgCN+nQEBtmjNSNIE6MLRaNJ2VC9pIuvMdRvScbJumw5Zvm+SICW9pqi6KBVuGjatqm11drmxzFpgZbKhO7pei4VagA)

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74705564/2887218) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58434389/2887218) but I'm not sure; your title wants just a union of all paths, but your question seems to only want a union of all paths whose property value is of type `{visible: boolean}`.  Which is it?

Comment: @jcalz all paths whose property value has visible prop

Comment: @jcalz Go ahead. I am not sure how to make the title clear

Comment: Your answer to the other post might solve my issue. Will take some time to read. Thanks

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NB4O4W) meet your needs? If so I could possibly write up an answer (although it's similar to the others); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance; might not be for a few hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sorts of deeply-nested [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) often have quite surprising and unpleasant edge cases, and there can be a fine line between a type which meets all your needs and one which results in obnoxious circularity warnings and compiler slowdowns.  So while I present one possible approach below which works for your example code, be warned that this is tricky and you might well hit a problem that requires a complete refactoring to overcome.

---

Anyway, here's one way to do it:

```
type _DKM<T, V> =
  (T extends V ? "" : never) |
  (T extends object ? { [K in Exclude<keyof T, symbol>]:
    `${K}.${_DKM<T[K], V>}` }[Exclude<keyof T, symbol>] : never)

type TrimTrailingDot<T extends string> = T extends `${infer R}.` ? R : T;

type DeepKeysMatching<T, V> = TrimTrailingDot<_DKM<T, V>>
```

The helper type `_DKM<T, V>` stands for `DeepKeysMatching<T, V>` and does most of the work.  The idea is that it takes a type `T` and should produce a union of all the paths in that type that point to a value of type `V`.  We'll see that it actually produces a union of these paths with a trailing dot appended to them, so we'll need to trim this dot afterward.

Basically: if `T` itself is of type `V`, then we want to return at least the blank path `""`.  Otherwise we don't and return `never`.  If `T` is not an object type we're done; otherwise we map `_DKM<T[K], V>` over each of the properties at keys `K`, and prepend each key `K` and a dot to it.  This gives us everything we want except for that trailing dot.

So `TrimTrailingDot<T>` will remove a trailing dot from a string if there is one.

And finally `DeepKeysMatching<T, V>` is defined as `TrimTrailingDot<_DKM<T, V>>`, so that we're just stripping that dot.

---

Armed with that we can define `getVisibilities()`:

```
declare function getVisibilities<T>(visibilities: T,
  path: DeepKeysMatching<T, { visible: boolean }> & {} 
): boolean;
```

It's [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `T` of the `visibilities` parameter, and then we limit the `path` parameter to be the union of paths of `T` that point to properties of type `{visible: boolean}`, hence `DeepKeysMatching<T, { visible: boolean }>`.

By the way, that `& {}` doesn't really do anything to the type (the empty object type `{}` matches everything except `undefined` and `null`, so intersecting a `string` with it will end up being the same string), but it does give IntelliSense a hint that we'd like it to display the type of `path` as a union of string literals instead of the type alias `DeepKeysMatching<{...}, { visible: boolean }>`. The alias might be useful in some circumstances, but presumably you want callers to be shown a specific list of values.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const visibilities = {
  food: {
    visible: true,
    fruit: {
      visible: true,
      apple: {
        visible: false
      }
    },
    snack: { visible: false }
  }
}

getVisibilities(visibilities, "food.fruit.apple");
// function getVisibilities(
//   visibilities: {...}, 
//   path: "food.fruit.apple" | "food" | "food.fruit" | "food.snack"
// ): boolean
```

Looks good.  When we call `getVisibilities(visibilities, ...`, we are then prompted for a `path` argument of type `"food.fruit.apple" | "food" | "food.fruit" | "food.snack"`.

```
getVisibilities(
   { a: 1, b: { c: { d: { visible: false } } } }, 
   "b.c.d"
);
```

Also looks good, we are prompted that only the path `"b.c.d"` is acceptable.

---

So we're done, and it works.  As I said earlier, I'm sure there are plenty of edge cases to deal with, but this at least answers the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAUg9gSwHYB4AqUIA9gSQEwGcpDgAnZAcygB8okBXAWwCMIyAaKAVUxzyIlyVWvWZsyAPigBeALAAoKFAAGAEgDeaAL4A6Td20qA3IsWhIUNBSbo+uAsVIUklaTKv2BxdRuQAzdigAJT0VKAB+EKgALitTBXNwaAB9ABEAaQBZdC4ANXdFZQAKDGwHQTzIqAAiGtj6CAA3dgBKWiKoUq9HKDgWACsIAGNgao0oAG0MqGQoAFEsYYAbBnwIFABrCBA4fysuQhBWOGXJAF0YzuV4ZBQMrnTs9Gnz-MlpbUnFlbWN7d2+zQh2OLFOFwaSGabTMCgs0DSEAgYAyO0IWQAhsBhgALKi5KAFWRWGwoJ45YGEj6w9YrDFkaD+BhIUYIOBIKCUCDAPIIQgIFgIZYIYAICCEdCSYpNPkCoUisWEOLAzpgLE4uKI5GokDorG4-GUiYy-ksZYQOJg04QDEc7TSABkUA02igAHo3VAUABab1QJ0uqADBikKA4iDLMDEADuIpxsyQuGWwsIeFTUDYyzg0cUrUtcGttoSsOG7NDJrlwtF4uJGk6-gL+DidaUyigFbNFqg5AYEA41yg-jIDBFzYHyg75riPb746gGLAYCnzrnE9lnbi-gxy1Tc+0A+0-dbykISAxw02zfb6+XW530H3rcfj8UXJ56-l1cI0o-VcVXBqBs4HwXQhxHYBdAXJcIBqVoEg9QdmVZdlOW5XlTU-RVikUBC1wwv9xWbXRiMPKAcM9ZQ1WADVaiAkCwJFSDF3Neo6EAxtWNoxtQOHEVOPY4DdFPc9NhqcioDzDMC3NW1YVfNDfwVcVigmDE4gARi4Fgr2GK8m2da9TVvbd01dMyoFImoWF0YZdHwWDjCAA)