# How to get value from object using string of object path in typescript without using eval?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In JS/typescript, lets say I have an object like this

```
var obj = {
  a: {
   b:{
    c:1
   }
  }
}
```

And I have a string `"b.c"`. How can I evaluate this using only those variables and get the value `1` from the object without using hacks like `eval` since typescript would complain.

Thanks

Comment:  do you mean `"a.b.c"` or something?

Comment: There's no built-in functionality anywhere in TS/JS that will do this so you'd have to write or import a deep indexing function (for runtime functionality) with a deep indexing type (for design time typing).  As such it looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74705564/2887218) where my answer there yields the code [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m0bRaw). Does that fully address your question or am I missing something?

Answer (score -2):

It I understood you question, the keys are known, if so you can use the '[]' to access it :

```js
const a = b.c
```

is the same thing as

```js
const a = b['c']
```

but in the second case you can of course use a variable.

Applying this to your object, it would look something like this :

```js
const obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 1
    }
  }
}

const outerKey = 'a'
const middleKey = 'b'
const innerKey = 'c'

const value = obj[outerKey][middleKey][innerKey]

console.log(value)
```

Hope it helped you !