# Typescript: interfaces properties to string literal types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So this is a question to all Typescript wizards.

If I have an interface, e.g

```
interface A {
  value: string
  child : {
     nestedValue: number
  }
}
```

is it possible to derive a type that contains all properties of that interface A as string literal types? Like this:

`type WhatIWant = 'value' | 'child.nestedValue'`

Thanks!

Comment: You would usually use `typeof A`, but I'm not sure if flattening nested objects would be possible at all. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQzkBucANgK4QBcyAzmFKAOa74IAWwxAJsldnvvhARaETgDUS5KiFIBbAEbRmyAL641OXGACeABxQBrCNuoB5GOgC8yI9oD2MNAG4gA Why do you need `child.nestedValue` type? What do you want to use it for?

Comment: @zerkms I want to write a type-safe function like this:


`performMagic('child.nestedValue')`

Comment: Even if you would be able to have a `child.nestedValue` type you wouldn't be able to use it as a properties path to traverse object type-safely. Assume you already have a value of `child.nestedValue` and try to implement the `performMagic`.

Comment: Starting with Typescript 4.1 this will be possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object