# TS4.1: Is there a way to define this property path type that isn't excessively deep?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Experimenting with the upcoming TypeScript 4.1's [template literal types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336), I tried to define a generic type that can check property paths.

Until TS 4.1, there was no possible way to type an expression such as `'foo.bar.baz'`, and you would have to settle for `string`. Now, with template literal types, I want to be able to type these property paths, and use them for things such as MongoDB queries and projection objects. For example:

```
db.someCollection.find({ 'foo.bar.baz': { $exists: true } });
```

This is the type that I came up with:

```
type PropsPath<T> =
    T extends object
        ? T extends any[]
            ? number
            : {
                [P in keyof T]: P | `${P}.${PropsPath<T[P]>}`
            }[keyof T]
        : '';
```

[Full example in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200921#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZxgQ2ACwDwBUB8UAvAFBTlS5QQAewEAdgCbJQIBGAVhAMbBkVBAfkrU6jFlDQMQAbQC6AwcqgiGAVwC27CHCUqKALigBvfQeWyYUAJYMoAawggEAM0rzj1gD5QABgAkJjAAvgB0QfBIqBg4uFby+CF+5gYhsk4u7riKFsYA5PkA3CQkdvRwrmg80ADKCJoQuODQZoKuCAjGbQbsaHDGGtq6JYIh+n0AXsbsnQA2ENIl4yQ8CAzIwFBgXogo6FjY9Y3NkIREUPkdCMWlaxtbYIjcfDbrXv3ANmhz2ABKvAQcCY2Ci+1iRwaTRa+AANFAhjo4PhzqZ9FdOmE+nB8sYAIwkEJFIA)

Sadly, this type is considered "excessively deep or possibly infinite" by TS compiler.
Is there any way to redefine it in a way that doesn't throw an error?

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object/58436959#58436959

Answer (score 3):

With TS 4.0, you can use [Variadic Tuple Types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0-beta/#variadic-tuple-types) to have the exact element type of an `Array` type. Combine that with [Recursive Type Aliases](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7-rc/#more-recursive-type-aliases), you can achieve what you want. Check out the TS Playground

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200921#code/PTAEG0HIEMCdcgXVAHwjekA0oB0-oA7AT3EWQFoA+dOBRAKABdiAHAU1AFEAPJ2aAGMmABVgB7VgGcR0JgAsAPABUaAXm58BwlTin8AloQDmZKgG4GzNpwBS4oytDs+7QgBMpofbCOnEOAAizq4eXj5+6gygMaDKIUxunhDIAPygkJCgAFzRsfEuiWEQRgBm7LCgAKpp1Tl5MQWhyeAAroQA1oTiAO6EOPi4ZRXVtQAGACQA3srgAAyIAL7TgctT9o5VQVSLY-Wx3oYmltYc1YQG4oTK4gCShImwUuzCl4SKVeqgDACQABRVBJJLxEYigdJ-DrZaoASjUVAAbg53DlQIR2AiKjCgcU-pDocNKrc4Yjkdj0rdUejMbArCwzrcpFULlcVF9wMpkIVgRBmW8bvdHs9XqzVLVStAADbPVH8VrsOk2UCyBQAeVKTm5xXEACMAFYvJhfKYNCAAaVARlAHXYxHEpTiiFyBwOszNXOaXl1BuEppdsXS4HdqHNA3wf1+Pyjbo9RRahO4kvYAFs3ExGFHM+kuEnUw8cclvYbI5mftmtEJRBJpCqlLX1Yocym01QqCXM9CoHMkO2ftCYwWvOBBgmm3mmFIM6Wy6BGXzWWO01JwIRWsmdRVEDQtck5Qrp1Hy-xK2JJDI5HWLw2Y63e1HoYuHsvV+vN4PQEXfQfD5pj8JTzWF6KPWGqPhOK5rhusBbm2359miGIVHeD4Vv+1bngowFXhqN5tv6-owow+Eup27oMIs4A2naDqcic9KcAAyhUBhSgYABe7DuCBmqeh++qGl8GzvLwf5VmetZYWqOGtjgkC4JAFhWCAoAAAIThQBjGN0sAKvRcQ2Ne75TEG0IRCYTqgKCiw4MotbvkxvisRxXHYWyoAaA5LGSuxnHcaoXy-LZF7vpMUwJgAYosuDTAmVS7N8BzKWpUgaVp4g6ZG6TKAZOHgOFATVDQkb9nZO5eKFEXxZlcR5cgxVoq0kqSicRiPBKgiMeIqbZWcJoHN60J9fhL7Qi+UGWAciwTbEOriOIkrQrN83sEQ00xHQnZ+rEQ3ETEPimUcxhrS61lbTEY0VGQWBnRAF3QTgyljHdZB7O44jsFIhCQEwoA9OlHSmoglg-HQABMg2lHNB2+CYFFA78dAAMzQ34ZCWIsipnMoH0-Ro3EMV17A9ewil6dj+ieU5nHuaAlPec5+OE8TikMIIVz6KArASD6TBvNCsiwLzUqKAASi86XuIodM+S5UlS0zNhUDgd2tjTO0ZHQuCg5A0IAIzkeYQA)

Further explanation:

- `ExtractPropsPath<T>`: This alias only keeps any member of `T` that is `string[]`. Eg: `['arr'] | ['arr', ...any[]]`, this alias will only keep `['arr']`
- `Join`: Join an `[...Elements][]` with a delimiter `D`. In this case, the delimiter is a dot `.`
- `PathOf`: the meat of the solution is here. `PathOf` returns a **Union Type** that will:

  - Returns `[key]` if `T[key]` is a primitive
  - Returns `[key] | [key, ...nested-if]` if `T[key]` is an object (note the `...`, we will be returning array type)
  - "nested-if" is where we check if

    - `T[key]` is an **Tuple** with 1 member (eg: `[number]`) then return `['0']` if member type is primitive, or we return recursive `PathOf<member>` (mark this point as {1})
    - `T[key]` is a **Tuple** with multiple members or an array type (eg: `[number, string]` or `number[]`) then

      - Check if the tuple is a union (eg: `[number, string]` -> `number | string`) then just return the recursive `PathOf`
      - If it's not the union, then it's an array type which we can use the same logic as {1}
- `SerializedPathOf`: Basically turns `PathOf` which is a union of `string[]` to a joined union of `string` with the delimiter `.` (eg: `['obj'] | ['obj', 'num']` -> `'obj' | 'obj.num'`)

Comment: That's really cool, even better than my own solution. Well done! I wish there was a way to support `'arr3.<any number>'`. There's a problem with the `Join<T, D>` definition though, in line 7.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by `'arr3.<any number>'`? And yeah that `Join<U, D>` is messing with me. Not sure why since I did assert `T extends string[]` so theoretically, `[unknown, ...infer U]` should infer `U` as a `string[]` but oh well. 

PS: changing `unknown` to `string` didn't fix it :)

Comment: I meant that I wished it could accept `arr3.100` (100 is just a random number) since `arr3` is of an unknown length.

Comment: I was trying to implement something the same but much smaller. (Currently no array support).

type GetObjectPossiblePaths<TData, TPath extends string> = TPath extends `${infer Left}.${infer Right}`
  ? Left extends keyof TData
    ? `${Left}.${GetObjectPossiblePaths<TData[Left], Right>}`
    : never
  : TPath extends keyof TData
  ? TPath
  : never;

But this doesn't work. If you have som time - could you help me to understand why this doesn't work, please?
My solution shows only 1 level of properties. It doesn't show 2 lvl as autocompletion but yells if 2 lvl doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, I finally came up with the following type:

```
type PropsPath<T extends object> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object
        ? `${string & P}` | `${string & P}.${PropsPath<T[P]>}`
        : `${string & P}`
}[T extends any[] ? (number & keyof T) : keyof T];
```

[Updated example in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200921#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZxgQ2ACwDwBUoQAewEAdgCbJQIBGAVhAMbAB8UAvFAN4BQU-UANowoAS1JQA1hBAIAZlFwBdAFyLhSgsTKVq9JsD4DjAfigADACRdkwOOIDmUAGSwAvuagAfC9dv3SJ1cYNwA6a3gkVAwcXA0WDyNjfjUrGztHF3dzHjdBfCISCio0UhBBTTMAClIAVwBbGgg4LOlZBVwASig1NvlFJQBuHh5xEjg5NEZoAGUEeohccGheY1o6NVXk-jr6tV2muGHjN2OBGgQEABs1C+uIUrP+NDg4NUEk5K3t4381f0cT2SbgANJ9jIIDs1NAB6GEWKFwCqecgICDIUgAcmAUAA7gg4JJPkNciNGAhSLYoGAAIxqSIodBYbBzBZLSBsTiY9aY4Y8cmUnFgABM9MQjJiLPmi2WnKgmJecFCNN5ZIpVLAiAYzFEFPpL2AojQV2wACUmATyNgGdFmayZRyQVBESw5d95YrlaEAAyYtQ03KDIA)

It works, but sadly doesn't cover cases where `T` has a nested property which is an array of unknown length (`any[]`).

Comment: Thanks! I'll use that!

Here's a newbie question: I noticed your type creates an object and immediately selects a property from that object, using keyof P. Why?

I was hoping something like this would work:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200921&ssl=5&ssc=17&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZxgQ2ACwDwBUoQAewEAdgCbJQIBGAVhAMbAA0sUAvFANYQgIAzKLgB8nAFBQpUmAWJlKPPoOFQA-FEnTtuANowAunJIUqtBs3WxEKdFjz6DIrdqkAuKAAMAJAG9kwHAAlqQA5lAAZLAAvp4urh6kEABuEHAA3OLiISRwAmiM0ADKCAC2ELjg0L7x5h41rtKkAK6lia00aZna0ZnRWYwIpAFQYABMHvBIqBg4JeWVkGJcAOTmAHQtpSuZ4kA

Answer (score 1):

Building on Amit's answer, this works for arrays too, though it doesn't account for tuples like Chau's.

```
type Path<T> = T extends Array<any>
  ? `${number}` | `${number}.${Path<T[number]>}`
  : T extends object
  ? {
      [P in keyof T]: (P & string) | `${P & string}.${Path<T[P]>}`
    }[keyof T]
  : never
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAFgHgCoD4oF4qqhAD2AgDsATAZygEEAnWuEZOEkdAKCigH4oADACQBvEgFcAtgCMItAL58oAH37CxUmbIB0w%20EjQBtNdNoBddPM5QAXLnxFSlKAHtJAKwgBjYJd5DLXLn0YKABLEigAawgQJwAzXBMbAApggDIoCmBaMIBzAEolFSE0jKzcrR0EFFQgswsAqFl9KJj41BNLGxIIADcZdnZQSCgAZSdxCFRwaBw-LlEKGRs5gJCyG0zskhz-UIpqMnEwm0knJwAbCBZLWUswJ0zl3eAQ4EuNsu3dig8nWgguhJjM84DkKDY6AwmJtchwGr9xBMSMBwTR6IxkEJQutSlscgAaKDEIgfPGNOGNdi3QbTUbjSbTXSIKg4JnIMYTKaQdBAA)

Comment: nice! It can be mixed with Chau's answer to support both, I guess?