# How to understand `[0, 1, 2, ...0[]]` in type definition in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I see some type definition like this in [Typescript: deep keyof of a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object/58436959):

```
type Prev = [never, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
    11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...0[]]
```

I can't understand what the last part `...0[]` means.

Is there a document for this? Thanks

Comment: It means `... 20]` or `... 20, 0]` or `... 20, 0, 0]` and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need two pieces of information to understand this type:

- [Rest elements in tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types)

> The last element of a tuple type can be a rest element of the form `...X`, where `X` is an array type. A rest element indicates that the tuple type is open-ended and may have zero or more additional elements of the array element type. For example, `[number, ...string[]]` means tuples with a `number` element followed by any number of `string` elements.

- you can restrict a type to one constant value:

```
const x: 0 = 0;
const y: 0 = 1; // ERROR: Type '1' is not assignable to type '0'.
```

Thus, the trailing `...0[]` in tuple type means: any number of zeroes