# Recursive type iteration of object does not properly associate keys with values in Typescript

Tags: typescript, template-literals, recursive-type

I'm trying to define a TypeScript type that matches strings which work as accessors similar to JsonPath on strictly typed objects. So for a object with the type

```
{ root: { inner: { child: string } } }
```

the string `$root.inner.child` should be a valid type, but `$root.something.else` should not be a valid type.

Here's what I've currently got ([Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTge0nUBBAxuiBnbC4A88SEKAljgDSxwQBmZAHlBI8BAHYAm2U2wcMhwDmUALxQA5JIB84gLAAoKDRLkcLNpx40yAWzLAyANwhKVKgPw16TKAC4oACnMWVxZEY2t23XgG8oAG0AaQgQKCEoAGtwhDpVTwpsAF1HITpSKAA1AEMAGwBXaABfVzcrRNI0TBw8QjyiiGoAAwASf3hbRhKOroZmH21eaShrSTbJBykAOkle-wBlASFhAHk4ADkIU0JYkHiq9WwZEpaZcorHDh3SS5UASgBuJSV0BA5%20TVy9MHzoCT%20S6IBDAACMjiBygqKmwhQARhCoFCYTC4fDFgikSjUbj0ZiMVjHJJjAVipJ7qiytCYSVKJTYQiAEyQhkVfHM1k03HshEEgksqSkpoU7m46ni%20nc6nUt4fL65Wq4fBIjzVEAYLDKwigSCHVg-P4QOQSCYg8EzdFgy18rE2wkOsGSJ5QAD0rqgAHV8NFeLleEJfFwIFw5Z9gFBFVr6oK1SgNUr6gRdRB9YxDf8TVI2ubreimfaCXnbY7nW6PYsABYIQr5LhQYCVxAAd0jHAb4GgpEQcGo8MKEa4CA0HFBAEIwwrE-gAMyOOM1aP4ZOdtMZ43ibO5%203Fh0Fjmll3uqAAYXwtHQwHyEUbLd4KZYcB7k4jUbq%20AALPPEJ4E0udauCQGr8mabmaCCgruu5FoWJZMmWx5nk%20ECXteDZNggzb3p2j7PooSjHgAEhA%20TIB2kDYEoD7LIIIgbNsuwEAAKlmTGaEGvD8LRojWGx1y3HALyKA%208D6IYJgAnwKwiFAAA%20UAcIUejwlk8nwhB-y5O2alkMIgZyXwIDKQg%20QGYp%20SmfJhTcLYNxcE8QA)):

```js
type PropertyAccessor<Properties, Prefix extends string = ''> =
  Properties extends Primitive
    ? Prefix : (
      Properties extends { [Key in keyof Properties]: infer Value }
        ? PropertyAccessor<Value, `${Prefix}${Prefix extends '' ? '$' : '.'}${StringOrNever<keyof Properties>}`>
        : never
      );

// Helper types
type StringOrNever<T> = T extends string ? T : never;
type Primitive = string | number | boolean | bigint | symbol | null | undefined;
```

It almost works. When looking at the following example:

```js
const example = {
    root1: {
        sub1: {
            subSub1: {
                subSubSub1: 'value'
            }
        },
        sub2: {
            subSub2: {
                subSubSub2: 'value'
            }
        },
    }
}

// Works as intended
const accessor1: PropertyAccessor<typeof example> = '$root1.sub1.subSub1.subSubSub1'; 

// Should throw an type error, but does not!
const accessor2: PropertyAccessor<typeof example> = '$root1.sub2.subSub1.subSubSub1';

// Correctly throws type error
const accessor3: PropertyAccessor<typeof example> = '$root1.sub1.subSub2.subSubSub1';

// Correctly throws type error
const accessor4: PropertyAccessor<typeof example> = '$root1.sub1.subSub1.subSubSub2';
```

it works for some strings, but not all. I think the issue is that, by deconstructing the object type into `keyof Properties` as Key, and `Value = Properties[keyof Properties]`, I would get something like `Key = 'sub1' | 'sub2'` and `Value = { subSub1: ... } | { subSub2: ... }`, so individual keys are not properly associated with their respective values. However, the fact that type errors are correctly thrown for the examples `accessor3` and `accessor4` gives me hope that it should be doable somehow.

Does someone have an idea how I could adapt the type such that type errors are thrown for `accessor2` as well, without `accessor1` throwing a type error?`

The entire code is available as [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTge0nUBBAxuiBnbC4A88SEKAljgDSxwQBmZAHlBI8BAHYAm2U2wcMhwDmUALxQA5JIB84gLAAoKDRLkcLNpx40yAWzLAyANwhKVKgPw16TKAC4oACnMWVxZEY2t23XgG8oAG0AaQgQKCEoAGtwhDpVTwpsAF1HITpSKAA1AEMAGwBXaABfVzcrRNI0TBw8QjyiiGoAAwASf3hbRhKOroZmH21eaShrSTbJBykAOkle-wBlASFhAHk4ADkIU0JYkHiq9WwZEpaZcorHDh3SS5UASgBuJSV0BA5%20TVy9MHzoCT%20S6IBDAACMjiBygqKmwhQARhCoFCYTC4fDFgikSjUbj0ZiMVjHJJjAVipJ7qiytCYSVKJTYQiAEyQhkVfHM1k03HshEEgksqSkpoU7m46ni%20nc6nUt4fL65Wq4fBIjzVEAYLDKwigSCHVg-P4QOQSCYg8EzdFgy18rE2wkOsGSJ5QAD0rqgAHV8NFeLleEJfFwIFw5Z9gFBFVr6oK1SgNUr6gRdRB9YxDf8TVI2ubreimfaCXnbY7nW6PYsABYIQr5LhQYCVxAAd0jHAb4GgpEQcGo8MKEa4CA0HFBAEIwwrE-gAMyOOM1aP4ZOdtMZ43ibO5%203Fh0Fjmll3uqAAYXwtHQwHyEUbLd4KZYcB7k4jUbq%20AALPPEJ4E0udauCQGr8mabmaCCgruu5FoWJZMmWx5nk%20ECXteDZNggzb3p2j7PooSjHgAEhA%20TIB2kDYEoD7LIIIgbNsuwEAAKlmTGaEGvD8LRojWGx1y3HALyKA%208D6IYJgAnwKwiFAAA%20UAcIUejwlk8nwhB-y5O2alkMIgZyXwIDKQg%20QGYp%20SmfJhTcLYNxcE8QA).

Comment: You are presumably looking for something like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mbk22W)... please see [the question this duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object) for more information on how to do it.