# How can I dynamically define a union type that covers all paths of an object in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, object, types, union-types

Image I have this object:

```
const data = {
  foo: "foo",
  bar: "bar",
  layer1: {
    foo: "foo",
    layer2: {
      foo: "foo",
      bar: "bar",
    },
  },
};
```

How could I define a union type of `string`s that has all possible *paths* (= I mean descending property chains such as `foo.layer1.foo` or `foo.layer1.layer2.bar` or also just `foo`, ...)

I tried lumping together random pieces but can't get any further and don't know how I could do this dynamically... Is there any clever way of doing this?

```
type Path =
  `${keyof typeof data}.${keyof typeof data.layer1}.${keyof typeof data.layer1.layer2}`;
```

This is would the type should look like ideally for `data`:

```
type Path = "foo" | "bar" | "layer1.foo" | "layer1.layer2.foo" | "layer1.layer2.bar";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized this is probably a duplicate of [Typescript: deep keyof of a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object). I didn't know how to formulate good search queries for this problem. I flagged my question as duplicate of the mentiond post. After a few changes [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436959/12834972) perfectly solved my problem:

```
type NestedObjectPaths = Paths<typeof data>;
```