# Typescript not understanding that T extends interface in a specific complex custom type

Tags: typescript

So I'm using the `Paths` type I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436959/3575645), full disclosure, I don't fully understand how it's built and it will probably assist me in understanding the problem, I'll have my implementation of it at the bottom. In summary if I have the interface:

```ts
interface Person {
  name: string,
  contacts: {
    email: string,
    phone: string,
  }
}
```

Then `Paths<Person>` would result in union of literal types:

```ts
'name' | 'contacts' | 'contacts.email' | 'contacts.phone'
```

But when trying to use it with a generic that extends some type, I'm running into weird troubles.

```ts
function foo<T extends Person> {
  let personParamGood: Paths<Person>;
  personParamGood = 'name' // great, works.
  
  let personParamBad: Paths<T>
  personParamBad = 'name' // typescript screams at me
  
}
```

The type error I get says

```
error TS2322: Type '"name"' is not assignable to type 'T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]-?: K extends string | number ? `${K}` | Join<K, T[K] extends object ? { [K in keyof T[K]]-?: K extends string | number ? `${K}` | Join<K, never> : never; }[keyof T[K]] : ""> : never; }[keyof T] : ""'.
```

I don't get why, shouldn't `T` basically be `Person`?

It does work on a simple type:

```ts
function foo<T extends Person> {
  let personParamGood: keyof Person;
  personParamGood = 'name' // great, works.
  
  let personParamGoodToo: keyof T
  personParamGoodToo = 'name' // great, works.
  
}
```

My implementation of `Paths`:

```ts
type Prev = [never, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, ...0[]];

type Join<K, P> = K extends string | number
  ? P extends string | number
    ? `${K}${'' extends P ? '' : '.'}${P}`
    : never
  : never;

export type Paths<T, D extends number = 10> = [D] extends [never]
  ? never
  : T extends object
  ? {
      [K in keyof T]-?: K extends string | number
        ? `${K}` | Join<K, Paths<T[K], Prev[D]>>
        : never;
    }[keyof T]
  : '';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `T` will never resolve **inside** the function implementation as it can be anything. You added an `extends Person` constraint on it but it can still be anything that extends `Person`. The actual `T` type is only known outside the function.

Notice how this code works when you hover the `person` variable:

```
interface Person {
  name: string,
  contacts: {
    email: string,
    phone: string,
  }
}

interface ExtendedPerson extends Person {
  address: string;
}

declare function foo<T extends Person>(): Paths<T>;

const person = foo<ExtendedPerson>();
```

But you'll never be able to make `T` (and thus `Paths<T>`) resolve to an actual type inside the function implementation, that's how generics work in TypeScript and any other language.

Comment: Thanks for the answer first of all, I understand what you're saying and it does make sense.

However I'm not understanding how `keyof T` does work inside the function and resolved?


**EDIT**: nevermind I do understand, now I'm just left to wonder how to make `Paths` also work like `keyof`, because that's the intended behavior, but that's another topic, thank you.