# Template literal type for a nested type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Given a two level nested type (never more, never less levels):

```
export type SomeNested = {
  someProp: {
    someChild: string
    someOtherChild: string
  }
  someOtherProp: {
    someMoreChildren: string
    whatever: string
    else: string
  }
}
```

I want to have the following union type:
`"someProp.someChild" | "someProp.someOtherChild" | "someOtherProp.someMoreChildren" | "someOtherProp.whatever" | "someOtherProp.else"`.

I have tried something along the lines of

```
type FirstLevel = keyof SomeNested
type SecondLevel = SomeNested[FirstLevel]
type Dot = `${FirstLevel}.${SecondLevel}`
```

but I am probably missing some condition.
Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m on mobile now but I’m sure I’ve written an answer before where this operation is called `Leaves`. Will look later

Comment: It’s https://stackoverflow.com/q/58434389/2887218. Of course if you only have two levels then you don’t need recursion

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the link, but to be honest I don't get it. Do you have maybe a simpler example? Or what concepts do I need to understand to build a type like I want?

Comment: You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxBRzw) for exactly two levels, using a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that you immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get a union.  Or you could use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQ5Xjw).  I'm happy to write up an answer where I explain it in more detail, if you agree that it meets your needs.

Comment: The code you provided is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, this question is asking specifically to get the union of dotted paths for an object type that consists of exactly two levels.  For those interested in the union of dotted paths for an object of arbitrary depth, you should look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58434389/2887218) instead.

---

By [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `SomeNested` with the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of its [known keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) `type FirstLevel = keyof SomeNested`, you are getting a union of the known property types:

```
type X = SomeNested[FirstLevel];
/* type X = {
    someChild: string;
    someOtherChild: string;
} | {
    someMoreChildren: string;
    whatever: string;
    else: string;
} */
```

And the keys of that union would only be the keys that appear in all members of that union (which would be nothing at all, for your example):

```
type SecondLevel = keyof SomeNested[FirstLevel] // never
```

Essentially by making these unions you have thrown away information about the correspondence between specific keys of `SomeNested` and their specific property types.  To fix it you will need to essentially iterate through the keys of `SomeNested` and look at the subproperties for each key separately.

One way to do this is with a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), which lets you iterate over keys and then make a property for each key.  For example:

```
type Mapped = { [K in keyof SomeNested]:
  `${K}.${Extract<keyof SomeNested[K], string>}`
}
/* type Mapped = {
    someProp: "someProp.someChild" | "someProp.someOtherChild";
    someOtherProp: "someOtherProp.someMoreChildren" | 
      "someOtherProp.whatever" | "someOtherProp.else";
} */
```

Each property of `Mapped` is a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) which starts with a particular key `K` from `keyof SomeNested`, followed by a dot, and then followed by the union of string keys from the corresponding property `SomeNested[K]`.  (Ideally you could just write `${keyof SomeNested[K]}`, but the compiler does not realize that these will definitely be strings for all possible `K`, so we can use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to convince the compiler that we're only looking at `string`-compatible keys).

Of course you don't really want `Mapped`, an object type with the same keys as `SomeNested`.  But you do want the union of its property types, so *now* you can index into it with the union of its keys:

```
type Dot = { [K in keyof SomeNested]:
  `${K}.${Extract<keyof SomeNested[K], string>}`
}[keyof SomeNested]
/* type Dot = "someProp.someChild" | "someProp.someOtherChild" | 
  "someOtherProp.someMoreChildren" | "someOtherProp.whatever" | "someOtherProp.else" */
```

And there you go!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgOQgZ2BAJlAvFAbwFgAoKKNRCABQCc4wAuQ088ypAYQAsBLAGyzMMtXgDsA5qzYcIAeWDcItHgKEVgoydIC+02QqW06DZsTIyqAWTi0IqwXbHDN4qRfIB3bgENMAN2UXLXc2KAh+NAhgt11SPRJSUEgoADFeWgwAGQhA-jwoAGsIEDgAM1gqVAxsJPBoOQY0AvgkaswsAG10zOAcvIBdAG5SAHoAKihkhqaC8zDZB3URNxGPCipDZSWYyTWdKAAfFnXZGzslp12JNbDvP1ygjRDbtgio6-2ocdG6lJgIABjOBiLD9CIFYqlCqtFDoDrdDLZR78AZQUajKBiR60P7QABCPiwABE4MACgADAAkBB6yLyOgAdDSAcDQeD+DoKejMdjArjEiRplArD4wJAcPgCFBOgBpKDiIolcqVNrw7ADRjSakEWVMmkAUQAHpofIDgAAeKEq2HtbBygYAGmebgAfFz4mNJsLReLsHNpOwqCYmFAAESyEOMxZ8QRho7hyP0MDRzaKbaxrBh15BpBbYzJ5gRtNGKNnWz2TNOePHYt59MFhiM+4BZQ1xMl5RR94QbPxb6-QXC0nkqUy+WK60wqrqrCa7U0vXMgjG03mq3K6dqmpdWVOl2Sd0U+KdKequE7gZeqb1KAjgp1mjJ1NcTPtx9lzsqN8J6SP-Ofkg5yVmo1YJv+DZRi2OLvgYkHPj28Y-EAA)