# How generate dotted-object-path type from Object?

Tags: typescript

How I can generate all paths of an object as String literal's with dot separator with [ts-toolbelt](https://github.com/millsp/ts-toolbelt)'s [`Object.Paths`](https://millsp.github.io/ts-toolbelt/modules/object_paths.html) and [`String.Join`](https://millsp.github.io/ts-toolbelt/modules/string_join.html) as Union type like this?

```typescript
// Object
const obj = {
  a: 'abc',
  b: 'def',
  c: {
    c1: 'c1',
    100: 'c2',
  }
}
// Type
type dottedType = 'a' | 'b' | 'c.c1' | 'c.100'
```

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436959) without ts-toolbelt:

```typescript
type Prev = [never, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...0[]]

type Join < K, P > = K extends string | number ?
  P extends string | number ?
  `${K}${"" extends P ? "" : "."}${P}` :
  never :
  never

type Leaves < T, D extends number = 10 > = [D] extends[never] ?
  never :
  T extends object ?
  {
    [K in keyof T] - ? : Join < K,
    Leaves < T[K],
    Prev[D] >>
  }[keyof T] :
  ""

// Object
const obj = {
  a: 'abc',
  b: 'def',
  c: {
    c1: 'c1',
    100: 'c2',
  }
}
// Type
type dottedType = Leaves < typeof obj >
// type dottedType =  'a' | 'b' | 'c.c1' | 'c.100'
```

How can I simplify this code with ts-toolbelt?

Comment: You'd think it'd just be `String.Join<Object.Paths<typeof obj>, '.'>` but that gets widened to `string`. Curious...

Comment: @AlexWayne , exactly I though the same. I think there is a missing step to iterate over the Union types of `Object.Paths`. But I don't know Typescript so well to understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You'd think it'd be this:

```
type ObjPaths = Object.Paths<typeof obj>
type DottedObjPaths = String.Join<ObjPaths, '.'> // string
```

But that gets widened to `string`.

The problem is that for some reason (probably a good reason) `Object.Paths` returns tuples with optional values. `ObjPaths` above is reported to be of type:

```
type ObjPaths = ["a"?] | ["b"?] | ["c"?, "c1"?] | ["c"?, 100?]
```

Note all the `?` declaring those values as optional. We need to remove those optionals to make `String.Join` happy.

Looks like `List.Required` does that.

Which we can use like so:

```
type ObjPaths = Object.Paths<typeof obj>
type NonOptionalObjPaths = List.Required<ObjPaths>
type DottedObjPaths = String.Join<NonOptionalObjPaths, '.'>
// "a" | "b" | "c.c1" | "c.100"
```

Which seems to do the right thing.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgeQEYCsCmBjGAaOAZRimADsBzOAXzgDMoIQ4AiGAZwFoYIIAbVJj4wWAKHHYIZdvAgY4AXkSi4cAIYAuOAHI1qbNrwq4qLdoAmmOoePYtCY6uwBGMy5urVzgAze3AJg8aUWpxUQB6cLgAFQBPMExRGHjMOAA5KWQwGGApNT4AHmiAPkVEOABtAGk4cjgAa0xYiDoYgF1OAH4taOq24KSUlAwABTUYAAt2MrQsXAA6Mcn2AuSElrg5dGLBhPTM7NyyfNmlqbKMsiycvMLT8amdtdSAEQgYGExze+Wy4lJKPMAFIQcgFS7XI4nUYPdgEbTzbSlSKsNQsOAAH1YqHRWJY2HmLlxrAJPm8YiAA)

Comment: Wow, really solid solution. Thank you a lot. I tried to merge your lines to a one-line generic type: `export type DottedObjectPath<T> = String.Join<NonOptional<Object.Paths<T>>, ".">`.

But I get this error?
**error TS2344: Type 'NonOptional<Paths<T, []>>' does not satisfy the constraint         'List<Literal>'.**
How I can solve this?

Comment: I, uh, I don't know... That's bizarre. :(

Comment: It doesn't work. Check out this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436959/8662476