# How to refactor this to provide the property name (string)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

The following is working code.  The question is specifically about refactoring to provide the string for property name used to compare by `isSame`.  Perhaps better renamed to `isPropValueSame`.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

const diff = _.differenceWith(sourceList, comparatorList, this.isSame);

isSame = (objA: any, objB: any) => (_.has(objA, 'id') && _.has(objB, 'id') ? objA['id'] === objB['id'] : false);
```

Looking to pass field/prop name string like `this.isSame('id'))`;

`objA` and `objB` would be the items from lists: `sourceList` and `comparatorList` and lists might look like:

```
const sourceList = [
    { id: 1, prop2: { prop21: someValue }, prop3: prop3Value },
    { id: 2, prop2: { prop21: someValue }, prop3: prop3Value },
    { id: 3, prop2: { prop21: someValue }, prop3: prop3Value },
];
const comparatorList = [
    { id: 1, prop2: { prop21: someValue }, prop3: prop3Value },
    //{ id: 2, prop2: { prop21: someValue }, prop3: prop3Value },
    { id: 3, prop2: { prop21: someValue }, prop3: prop3Value },
];
```

With above test case data (note `comparatorList` has second item commented out), then the output of comparator would return the item where `id` equals `2` because it does not find it during comparison by delegate function `isSame`.

Comment: What are `objA` and `objB` supposed to be then?

Comment: [Closure](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-closures-explained-with-example/) that accepts prop name and returns isSame(a, b) function?

Comment: I'd try provide the types of objA and objB. Without that typescript has no info to infer the return type.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay it doesn't make a difference here.  Code works as provided.  The question is specifically about refactoring to provide the `field name` as string to the delegate func.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're looking for more than just a closure around the key – doesn't seem like type-safety is a concern for you so could be as simple as:

```js
const isSame = (key: string) => (objA: unknown, objB: unknown) =>
  _.has(objA, key) && _.has(objB, key) && _.get(objA, key) === _.get(objB, key);
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-cookies-07y4ey?file=/src/index.ts)

If you can live without having type checking on the key then that would suffice, but if you need it then I'd refer you to this [previous answer on recursive access paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71945264).

Comment: I think the `typescript` tag gave the wrong impression of the sort of answer you were looking for.

Comment: awarded because you're first AND provide link to recursive paths.   i ask questions for the learning.  thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a closure to which you pass the prop/attribute of interest:

```js
const isSame = (prop) => {
  const issame = (a, b) => (_.has(a, prop) && _.has(b, prop) ? a[prop] === b[prop] : false);
  return issame;
};

const someValue = 42;
const prop3Value = 3;

const sourceList = [
  { id: 1, prop2: { prop21: someValue }, prop3: prop3Value },
  { id: 2, prop2: { prop21: someValue }, prop3: prop3Value },
  { id: 3, prop2: { prop21: someValue }, prop3: prop3Value },
];
const comparatorList = [
  { id: 1, prop2: { prop21: someValue }, prop3: prop3Value },
  // { id: 2, prop2: { prop21: someValue }, prop3: prop3Value },
  { id: 3, prop2: { prop21: someValue }, prop3: prop3Value },
];

console.log(_.differenceWith(sourceList, comparatorList, isSame("id")));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can't award twice.  upvoted for effort.  thanks!

Comment: No worries. I wasted time between adding the initial comment on closures and getting a code snippet to work before posting an answer. My loss! This is a primary use case for closures, though there are [others](https://www.frontendmag.com/insights/advantages-of-closures-in-javascript/).

Comment: yes.  i didn't even think (or realize) i could stack the closures. haha!  i am glad i asked.