# Typescript: Create union type based on existence of sub keys in an object

Tags: typescript

Wondering if there's a way to use `keyof` and string templates in typescript to make a union type based on both keys + subkeys

```
const object = {
  level1Key1: {
    some: "data"
  },
  level1Key2: {
    nestedKey: { more: "data" },
    anotherNestedKey: { more: "data" },
  }
}
```

Is there any way to generate a type using `typeof object` to make the following union type without using any hardcoded strings (as in not doing `keyof typeof object.level1key2`)

```
type desiredType = "level1Key1" | "level1Key2.nestedKey" | "level1Key2.anotherNestedKey";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: deep keyof of a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object)

Comment: By what criterion are you excluding `"level1Key1.some"` and `"level1Key2"` from your desired type?

Comment: @jcalz, by the value type being a string rather than an object

Comment: The value type of `object.level1Key2` is not a `string`, and yet it is not present either.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mp9QpW) work  for you? Please test it out against your use cases.  If it meets them I can write up an answer explaining it; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That seems to be working the way I expect. An explanation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible approach:

```
type MyPaths<T extends object> = keyof T extends infer K ? K extends string & keyof T ?
  T[K] extends object ? `${K}${PrependDot<MyPaths<T[K]>>}` : never
  : never : never;

type PrependDot<T extends string> = [T] extends [never] ? "" : `.${T}`;
```

This defines a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) called `MyPaths<T>` which takes an object type `T` and produces a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of dotted paths to property values which are something I'll call *shallow objects*.

For example, in `{a: {b: {c: "d"} } }`, the only path you'd get is `"a.b"`.  The path `"a"` points to `{b:{c:"d"}}`, which is an object, but it has subproperties, so it isn't shallow.  The path `"a.b.c"` points to `"d"` which isn't an object.
Only `"a.b"` points to a shallow object, `{c:"d"}`.

Here's how it works.  First, we want `MyPaths<T>` to take the set of keys `keyof T` and split them up into individual `string` keys `K`.  For each such key, we will perform the necessary type operation, and then we will collect the results into one big union.  We do this by making `MyPaths<T>` a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) over `keyof T`.  Hence the `keyof T extends infer K ? K extends string & keyof T ? ... : never : never`, where `...` is the type operation for each `K`.

That type operation is another conditional type check; if the property type of `T` at key `K` (aka `T[K]`) is not an object (aka `object`), then we want to return nothing (aka `never`) for this property.  If the property *is* an object, then we need to prepend the current key `K` to the result of a recursive call to `MyPaths<T[K]>`, give or take a dot.

I mean, if `MyPaths<T[K]>` is `never`, then `T[K]` is a shallow object and we want to just return the current key `K` with no dot after it.  But if `MyPaths<T[K]>` is some union of strings, then we want to add a dot in between.  That's pretty much the way `PrependDot<T>` is implemented (put a dot before the string `T` unless `T` is `never`, in which case, just use an empty string).

That's what `` `${K}${PrependDot<MyPaths<T[K]>>}` ``, does.  It's a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) that does the string concatenation of `K` and `MyPaths<T[K]>`, with `PrependDot` taking care of whether or not to insert a dot after `K` or just an empty string.

---

Let's test it out:

```
type DesiredType = MyPaths<typeof object>;
// type DesiredType = "level1Key1" | "level1Key2.nestedKey" | "level1Key2.anotherNestedKey"
```

Looks good to me!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArApsWBeGBvAUDGANsgG7IECMA0sgJ7kBc2e+MEIAtsowEQAmAhlH7dmAXwA0zIqQrUaAJka4WMMMmjJecpTHYgATlxh9BwmBOb5+YEFAAWyfQDl1UTduy6DRk0O7nJfFEcYJwoGgAHZBgABUMosF4AEVsAHgAVGGQADzdEiFYofQBLMABzAD4YTABtdIBdLNzkfJgatVJ9RoB+Y39GAAMAOgASLHTRAYBuHDDI6IBZGhjBOwgMprzeAoQUNCrMAGtaEAAzGEycrYLS08cYShhex6uW7cKS8pgAMhhjmjOFyezHSNUojVerV2qFgvQGY0oojGcWQCWSaSWK3s61B4IqFUmMEYHUczGJJHu5M6MzmURgSXUxUMvHS82qMExq3W4SigOh+xmAHpBTAedEGRAmZpWXTMNxpGQqLRyP4AD7GBWyWjyIZqDRaWhqjUUrUKIbWWwOZyudyGoA)