# Get return type from an object path in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have an object that contains nested objects, which are all functions. It has define type and it looks like this:

```
interface ObjFnc {
   foo: {
     fnc1: () => Promise<{ data: string; message: string; }>;
     fnc2: () => Promise<{ data: number; message: string; }>;
   };
   bar: {
     fnc3: () => Promise<{ data: User; message: string; }>;
   };
}
```

Now I have a function where you can pass a path to the function, but I want to also get the return type because it is already defined and to avoid double definition.

```
const caller = (path: Path) => {
    // calls the function based on the provided path
    // Resolves the promise and returns the content of 'data'
}
```

The `Path` type is defined as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436959/8328193). It contains all available paths, like `'foo.fnc1'`, `foo.fnc2` and so on.

Is it possible, and if so, how can I get the return type from the called function, let's say that we call it like this

```
const foo = caller('foo.fnc1')
```

how to know that `foo` has a `string` type?

Edit: Updated the question

Comment: Well, if it's only two levels deep, something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WP95Ew) could work.

Comment: @kelly Working nice, however, there can be multiple levels, at most 4