# Typescript split string and validate type

Tags: typescript, string, validation, split

Let's say i have a string value of `ReplaceText::some.other.property`, I'd like to split this value by the delimeter of `::` and validate the types of each input

```
type Action = 'ReplaceText' | 'ReplaceImage';

type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
    string extends S ? Action[] :
    S extends '' ? [] :
    S extends `${infer T}${D}${infer U}` ? [T, ...Split<U, D>] : [S];
    

declare function translate<P extends string>(path: P): Split<P, '::'>;
const [action, dotString] = translate('ReplaceText::some.other.property');
```

This returns the values, but action is not of type of `Action`, I'm not quite sure where to begin here!

eg, if i did:

```
const [action, dotString] = translate('ActionThatDoesNotExist::some.other.property');
// id expect validation errors because this action does not exist!
```

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed up my typos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a string literal type like:

```
type Action = 'ReplaceText' | 'ReplaceImage';
type ActionWithPath = `${Action}::${string}`
```

Now `ActionWithPath` is any string that starts with an `Action`, followed by `::` and then any string.

Then just use that type as your constraint:

```
declare function translate<P extends ActionWithPath>(path: P): Split<P, '::'>;
```

And the rest works like you expect:

```
translate('ReplaceText::some.other.property'); // fine
translate('ActionThatDoesNotExist::some.other.property'); // error
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAymA2BLYAeGUIA9gQHYBMBnKQ4AJ0VwHMAaKAEQ2zyJPMqoD4oBeAKCiC2FakxwFi6APxQAggGNgiAPa4A2gF0oALgFD0WcawDkxqDM069gg8wlQABgBIA3pQBmEMlAAqAX1d6ALdcT28AVT8Hcyg1HzoAOiS4JFRwunpOLW1YmA0Abj4i0Eg5RRVcXihjACUIBABDeQgfQzMAH2q6xuaASQBbBqoIY0KS6AUlVQB1ZAALAAUG4Dmq5xdJir9tbVdSESoooSgi-Ah5eAayaHcAV1xy1ShyBtxCS5wUBbEWYk2Z+ZLFacAAUYGWcxyCwAlDkUsgvnRjDtjJwxmRXu9lhAQbV6pdmq1sDtCMp+hAEsoVl4EmAyMpIGRQMZofkoAB6dlQdyUCB8F5vD444z-XA+ObLejKCCEAByVIAophEKQSWSKVS5jS6QyvMzWRyuV56WQinwgA)

---

Note: deriving a dotted object path is much trickier and out of scope of this question, but you can start here: [Typescript: deep keyof of a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object/58436959#58436959)

Comment: I actually have already solved the dot notated part :)