# Unable to type function to retrieve values from nested objects using array values

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, reduce, tslint

```
// nested object
const obj = {
  one: {
    two: {
      three: 'xxxx',
    },
    four: {
      five: 5,
    },
    six: [1, 2, 3],
  },
}
```

I want to get a value from the above nested object using key.

The sample below works in javascript, but I can't define the type properly in typescript.

```
const result = ['one', 'two', 'four'].reduce(
  (acc, key) => acc[key],
  obj,
)
// undefined

const result = ['one', 'two', 'three'].reduce(
  (acc, key) => acc[key],
  obj,
)
// xxxx

const result = ['one', 'six'].reduce(
  (acc, key) => acc[key],
  obj,
)
//  [1, 2, 3]
```

tslint

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ one: { two: { three: string; }; four: { five: number; }; six: number[]; }; }'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ one: { two: { three: string; }; four: { five: number; }; six: number[]; }; }'.ts(7053)`

I understand that the type checking does not work because "one" in the array is a string and the key from reduce is "one".
However, I can't think of a solution.
Please let me know what type definition would work.

Comment: Please check out this discussion, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436959/14306019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you defined a type which is a record with a string key and any value:

```
type kv = Record<string,any>;
```

Then your original object is itself a record with a string key, and either another `kv` or `any` value:

```
const obj : Record<string, kv | any> = {
  one: {
    two: {
      three: 'xxxx',
    },
    four: {
      five: 5,
    },
    six: [1, 2, 3],
  },
}
```

Then your warnings go away [Live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=2&pln=11&pc=2#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGAuASgU1AJwCYB5psBLMAcwBoYBrANxgB8YBDMATwD4YBeGAbwBQMOGAwp+Q4TCgB3EOMFSpUABbYMYmAHIAHnp1aKk4QF8jSgGYgArtgXGpF4rU0BWc1LMOIxHeIDaAIxUAExUAMwAuh5eJgICUGwADhg09LyYOAREpJSsnADc8aCQsOoQ1gA2UIE8MP5a4BiG2rIgLVpWtlqRAHTquNbAGAAUkiPMwMBU1BhsAJQ8XJPA-rNs0ZIIiEbzAgD0+zDWYLgYTqK4xeDQMOVVUCF1DU0dbW9qGj39GIPDY8IJlMZnNFtxllM1nNNsJtrsDkd9DprqU7hgKtVws9GqIOj4DH0BkNRuMViCFksWJD1jC4Eh4YdhEFQhFIkA)