# TypeScript Type for Getting All Nested Key Paths of an Object (Including Arrays and Their Paths)

Tags: typescript, key

I'd like to find a way to have a type in TypeScript that will take in some object type and get all the nested key paths, including any properties that might be arrays and indexing into those and getting those properties on any objects inside those arrays. I don't however, want any of those nested arrays' built-in properties (like "push", "pop", etc. to appear.) I have seen a number of solutions that do this and it's not exactly what I am looking for. If I have this object:

```
const person = {
    name: 'Jim',
    address: {
        street: '1234 Some Street',
        city: 'Some City',
        state: 'Some State'
    },
    hobbies: [
       { 
           name: 'Sports'
       }
    ]
}

type RESULT = DeepKeys<typeof person>
```

, I'd expect these key paths to be `name | address | address.street | address.city | address.state | hobbies | hobbies.${number} | hobbies[${number}] | hobbies.${number}.name | hobbies[${number}].name`

Is this possible to do this without getting all the array methods and any extra keys in the union that aren't valid?

I have tried a number of types I have found online but none have satisfied this exactly.

Comment: Such deeply recursive types always have crazy edge cases and you mention having problems with existing types online so I'm a bit worried that this will end up being frustrating for both of us, but... does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wRenEW) meet your needs? It gives you the type you expect for your specific example as presented. Does it work well enough for your actual use cases? Or is there some dealbreaker you can't resolve yourself?  If it works for you I'll write up an answer explaining it; otherwise, please [edit] your question with a corresponding example.

Comment: @jcalz That is literally perfect! I know you are super busy on here but if you do have an extra moment, I'd love for you to do the quick walk-through on how you got to this just so I can expand my own knowledge a bit. I feel pretty solid with generics but when it gets to something this nutty, I'm definitely out of my element.

Appreciate you!

Comment: Actually now that I look at it one more time, the only thing that might possibly block my actual use case is the need for that as const on the input object. I'm assuming there is no way around that?

Comment: How do you expect TS to know that 0 is an index and 1 is not otherwise? I mean, check the type of `person` in your IDE without the const assertion, and tell me how you want to deal with it.  …. Also could you take your time and be sure there’s no other thing that will prevent you from accepting my eventual answer? The reason I asked in the first place was to prevent a situation where I write an exhaustive answer that turns out not to be applicable.

Comment: That makes sense about the index. For my use case I am basically wanting this type to be able to take an initial values object of a form and be able to give me a union of all its nested keys so that when I go to hook up an individual input field, the input field name can be strongly typed for the purpose of the user not making an error coming up with the correct name of the field. (more on next comments, sorry...)

Comment: Normally this wouldn't be an issue but a lot of the forms I have worked with where I've gotten into trouble with this using a library like Formik is where you have a field array and you want to name one of those fields in the array in such a way that allows the library to access its value correctly, i.e. `person.hobbies.${ index }.name` might be the name of that specific field in the field array.

Comment: So in that case, the very specific indices are probably not needed. At least the user at that point will get some error if the name they put in at least deviates from that shape. But also the auto-complete would be nice. Either way, if the type is at minimum aware of the fact that a nested property is an array and that array has objects with nested properties, then I'm golden! Again, appreciate all of your great work!

Comment: Im not sure what you want me to do from here. Could you either give me the go-ahead to write up my code as-is, or [edit] your question to ask something possible with a particular desired output union? If `as const` is a dealbreaker then the answer is “this is not achievable as asked”.

Comment: I went ahead and edited my question to go with the more "generic" index route (not as const). You can take it from there and go that direction with it if able.

Comment: I see the update and I think I can make that work, but I’m not at a real computer now; will look when I get a chance.

Comment: No rush at all! Thank you, sir

Comment: Okay try [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wOKBMw) and tell me if there are any other problems before I work on an answer.

Comment: That's the one! Thank you!!

Comment: Okay I'm going to write up an answer; if you do find a problem now I hope you'll just work on it yourself or ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I've definitely written this sort of thing before, see [Typescript: deep keyof of a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58434389/2887218) and other similar questions, but deeply recursive types like this *always* have bizarre edge cases, and different people seem to have quite different opinions about what the right behavior should be in those cases.  So in what follows I'm targeting the particular example from the question.  For other cases, it might not do what readers expect.  And fixing such deeply recursive types can sometimes involve fairly radical refactoring.  Beware.

---

The basic approach looks like this:

```
type DeepKeys<T> = T extends object ? (
    { [K in (string | number) & keyof T]:
        `${(
            `.${K}` | (`${K}` extends `${number}` ? `[${K}]` : never)
        )}${"" | DeepKeys<T[K]>}` }[
    (string | number) & keyof T]
) : never
```

This is a *distributive object type* (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) of the form `{[K in KK]: F<K>}[KK]`, a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) into which I immediately [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `F<K>` for all `K` in the union `KK`.  In this case, `KK` is `(string | number) & keyof T`, meaning all the serializable (non-`symbol`) keys of `T`. And `F<K>` is a big [template literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) thing of the form

```
`${(`.${K}` | (`${K}` extends `${number}` ? `[${K}]` : never))}${"" | DeepKeys<T[K]>}`
```

There's two parts to it concatenated together.  The left part is `` (`.${K}` | (`${K}` extends `${number}` ? `[${K}]` : never)) ``. It always includes the key prefixed with a dot `.`.  If `K` is numeric-like, then it also includes the key in square brackets `[`⋯`]`.  The right part is `"" | DeepKeys<T[K]>}`. It includes the empty string (so the dotted/bracketed key is included with no suffix) and `DeepKeys<T[K]>` (so it recursively adds the keys of the current property as a suffix).

This recursive thing gets us most of the way there. Let's try it on your example:

```
type Result = DeepKeys<typeof person>
/* type Result = ".name" | ".address" | ".address.street" | ".address.city" |
 ".address.state" | ".hobbies" | `.hobbies.${number}` | `.hobbies[${number}]` |
 `.hobbies.${number}.name` | `.hobbies[${number}].name` | ".hobbies.length" |
 ".hobbies.toString" | ".hobbies.toLocaleString" | ".hobbies.pop" | ".hobbies.push" | 
 ".hobbies.concat" | ".hobbies.join" | ".hobbies.reverse" | ".hobbies.shift" |
 ".hobbies.slice" | ".hobbies.sort" | ".hobbies.splice" | ".hobbies.unshift" | 
 ".hobbies.indexOf" | ".hobbies.lastIndexOf" | ".hobbies.every" | ".hobbies.some" |
 ".hobbies.forEach" | ".hobbies.map" | ".hobbies.filter" | ".hobbies.reduce" |
 ".hobbies.reduceRight" | ".hobbies.find" | ".hobbies.findIndex" | ".hobbies.fill" | 
 ".hobbies.copyWithin" | ".hobbies.entries" | ".hobbies.keys" | 
 ".hobbies.values" | ".hobbies.includes" */
```

So the two problems here are:

- Arrays include all the array property names, and
- All keys are prefixed with a dot.

Let's fix those.  First, we can wrap `T` in a `FixArr<T>` which checks if `T` is an array, and if so, omits every property present on all arrays, except for `number` (because we want `number` in our output).  Like this:

```
type FixArr<T> = T extends readonly any[] ? Omit<T, Exclude<keyof any[], number>> : T;
```

Next, we can write a type to drop any initial dot from a string, and put that as the output.

```
type DropInitDot<T> = T extends `.${infer U}` ? U : T;
```

So let's rename the old `DeepKeys` as `_DeepKeys`, a helper type, and use `FixArr<T[K]>` instead of `T[K]`:

```
type _DeepKeys<T> = T extends object ? (
    { [K in (string | number) & keyof T]:
        `${(
            `.${K}` | (`${K}` extends `${number}` ? `[${K}]` : never)
        )}${"" | _DeepKeys<FixArr<T[K]>>}` }[
    (string | number) & keyof T]
) : never
```

And then `DeepKeys` is

```
type DeepKeys<T> = DropInitDot<_DeepKeys<FixArr<T>>>
```

so we make sure that we fix `T` if it's an array, perform `_DeepKeys` on the result, and then `DropInitDot` it.  That gives us

```
type Result = DeepKeys<typeof person>
/* type Result = "name" | "address" | "hobbies" | 
"address.street" | "address.city" | "address.state" | 
`hobbies.${ number } ` | `hobbies[${ number }]` | 
`hobbies.${ number }.name` | `hobbies[${ number }].name` */
```

as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgDwIICcUB4AqA+KBeKTKCBYCAOwBMBnKFCAQ0oHtyAbEKB8kAbQF0oAfigB5ALZxgWADRQAoggDGbAK6UI6ANYQQzAGZceAueVXiARhBTZcALkIBuAFDPQkKAH0AIhAhgAaV1qLFwCIhIyKlpmCwArCCVgYSgACmcoTKgAbyheAKg4cjTqYBQigHMoAB8oM0trAEooADIoHT1DTH47DKz+gAMAEmz0-vGsgYA6EYCAXwGatOHs+cXIihooFfqrFAWUgd5Zuf5Fh3IIADcmvonGuZGAIielnz9A4PR4ZDQsfP4tgOc14dxKZUqS12TVa7V0BkI-GczQu12srnc0G8KGYYAAkuQpN5mNIcPhCMRSJtaNMRkV9NYoABVA4iJlQByYFxucBYj5BEAhMkEbG4glEknod7+AUhH6oDA4WyuZzkBjiCDUMAMJTQABCDGocCUOTBmKgvhlX2FFI20SgsQSSRSYwmOTyBSK4PK5CqtWhKGabQ6CO6vTd4xWrojE1pqwOtVSKzWlKiWx25j2rO2x3jZw5dTRgbBEcaJbdj2yLyWls+gv+AUBc22UBB5cyqVKPr9dUzMOD8K6SP6KMLNxQZt5UAASprVGxkiL+V9MQjIChqKxsGCAPQAKig5tn1Hni6gTymao1r1qF6YlHo1GoN-PU3vj+oUy7fmAL7vlAfTVPyUKQQBvEt-0Ap8v2ABgyD-KYAAtYgsOBNRfaZkIsVDNRmXIA1bFtakwlC0OoXNewaFBW3zaoSxI7CyLwyi9lbS91QgRZiKQ0jNQogjTnYjUuNfLCcM-NgKAqYBEPA8YLzEpjgGYABlCFfQQxTcOUgAZZglAYSS1O7TTeM-MBcVMxjcLAVRqFkpYIJ46zgNYAzfyWBSzKmOJmCKKzxKmehx2oCAAqY+y4H0Dy6Pk5zAuoNhjTCzz4oi5gUBi0TvK1JLdXC3DVHISLopfJytM-IoNAQUR9AKiTDWAAlqtq+qpiLMDUoqr9mGvGpyu8-QMvkHUHNvNLcPEBgwDa-Q4AXaw2voShVHy-q4u65bVogac4AqRCsq8lypjmqhZqq5qSHOtg2DKjbvKUXEQAAdSkRD-K67yKAhdDPuOjpn0c+7jquQzVF+8buqKFR1F+vcd2cOZnEe4rknXTdigIbIwSvCAHAAcgAKTgcR8ZkMF3yAhxsYjb8IGAAmAEYACYAGYABYoBU3roGMn8yfbKAQNAAnuY1KAAGFQIF2nYLIUWea5uWIHxsE5nJ-oKocUEIxpmNMlx0WLMy6hVYjJH+iRJGjznBdyVrWV0FXQx0a3Zx90PKdj1Pcknlxv9KafP8KrKp5A8-OnDvDqZhc629o9KOCUtqZwBm6kYWMZZsRLTsz+L7ajThE1P0-wgu2NxnOKvzqiaKEzioHhoA)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you again for working through this!