VueJS 3.4 - Computed value to get from two sources but set in one
The logic in my app is to fetch some array of objects from API with @tanstack/vue-query, update some of those objects and send a patch request only for the updated objects.
So I created an empty array in Pinia store that will hold the updated objects and at the end send only those objects to the patch request.
Tried a few ways and this seemed like the simplest way to do it:
const store = useBlocksStore();
const { blocks } = useBlocksAPI();
const { activeBlock } = storeToRefs(store);

  const block = computed(
    {
      get() {
        const blockId = activeBlock.value ?? 0;
        if (store.blocks[blockId]) {
          return store.blocks[blockId];
        }
        return blocks.value[blockId];
      },
      set(value: Block) {
        const blockId = activeBlock.value ?? 0;
        store.$patch((state) => {
          state.blocks[blockId] = value;
        });
      },
    }
  );

<input v-model="block.properties.left" type="text" />

So my expected behaviour is the getter to check if the block with some ID is available in store, meaning it has already being modified after fetching from the API, return that value if not return the value from the API, and then the setter to always set the modifed values in the store.
But I get this error instead [Vue warn] Set operation on key "left" failed: target is readonly. Proxy(Object) {top: 25, bottom: 25, left: 0, right: 0} , so I guess it tries to modify the value from the API.
Any idea what am I missing here or not understand, or any suggestions to accomplish this with minimal repetitive code to be able to use this in many other components to update different block properties.
Sandbox

You're not setting block.value anywhere. Instead you're deeply modifying block.value.properties.left, which is a bad practice and doesn't work any way for the reason listed in the error. It's unknown what properties.left is and why it's readonly

i can't wrap my head around the v-model :/ i thought that since the getter is returning the block and by modifying the nested value the setter would get the block with modified value :/

i'm not sure how to approach this issue, am I even gonna be able to solve it with one v-model helper for all the values in the block object or i'm gonna have to create some composable to handle em all separately

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and describe how exactly you want it to work. It's unknown what's this object {top: 25, bottom: 25, left: 0, right: 0} and why it's readonly, you'd have this problem regardless of v-model. "i thought that since" - it doesn't work this way. v-model is syntax sugar that means block.value.properties.left = $event.target.value on input. You can only trigger set() in writable computed with block.value = .... Since you already use pinia, you probably need some logic to be added to store actions instead of scattering it among the composables

Just edited my post with a link to sandbox. Well what i'm trying to accomplish is to create some v-model "hook" to I can reuse in different components that will handle the block object which can be nested. The initial value of the block should come from an API endpoint, and when some of the block's data is modified, that block to be saved in a store. So, after the user finished modifying bunch of different blocks i can check the pinia store and see which ones are modified so i'll send Patch request only for them, without updating all from the response.

So it's readonly because it's data from vue query, makes sense. You need to sort it out how it's supposed to work in the end. It needs to be cloned the store to be made writable, which you likely didn't do in the question. Do you update data from a query at some point? Then there should be logic to sync the store with remote data. You probably need to have parametrized getter and action in the store to update the properties from "properties" . Yes, there can be a helper to create a writable computed suited for v-model, but it will be as small as calling a getter and an action.

Had an answer with similar nested data in the store https://stackoverflow.com/a/78693779/3731501 , parametrized getters would be similar. As for patching, I'd suggest to store the copy of original data (probably it's "data" from the query, it shouldn't go out of sync with the store) and use diff against store data before sending it. This will make "dirty" fields which values weren't changed to not be sent. The case isn't really different than editing any complex form, you store form state in local state and then create a diff payload for PATCH request

Well the idea was the data from query to not be updated until you save the data from the store, and when you save the data from the store to clean up the store and refresh the query data so i'll always have latest data displayed. That's why in the getter in my example I'm checking if the data exists for the block exists in the store then use that one if not just use the one from the query. I want to avoid saving the whole data in pinia which can be a lot, since vue-query already have a caching mechanism on it's own.

i'll check out the question that linked, thanks! And yes, it's no different then handling some complex form with nested objects... i wanted to save only the updated blocks in the store so I don't loop through all of them when patching and looking for updated fields to patch. Like this i'll always update anything that is saved in pinia

Unless there are hundreds to thousands of records in a query and the lag was measured, i wouldn't bother with the optimization, both approaches will work fine. I posted, here's a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/blocks-forked-q2mqxx

no, there could be 1-200 records tops... I just felt that it's not the right approach, the initial idea seemed like a good solution... i can't open you sandbox, i guess it's not set to public access... but i'll try to apply your code in the answer ... thanks!

The original idea not bad, especially because readonly state is already there and it cannot be mutated. I see, I fixed access rights

The problem is that block.properties.left is readonly data from the query, it needs to be cloned before it can be mutated. The whole logic to manage store data can be moved to the store. It's generally not a good practice to directly mutate data from the store in v-model without an action, this also needs to be taken into account.
The store can either be filled with data lazily and fall back to data from the query, as was tried in the question. That there's a case for changing deeply nested data suggests there should be a separate action to change block fields:
export const useBlocksStore = defineStore("blocks", {
  state: () => ({
    _query: markRaw(useBlocksQuery()),
    blocks: {},
  }),
  getters: {
    getBlock() {
      return (id) => {
        // Avoid reactivity bugs by eagerly accessing data to track it
        const readonlyBlock = this._query.data.value[id];
        return this.blocks[id] ?? readonlyBlock;
      };
    },
  },
  actions: {
    updateBlock(id, value) {
      this.$patch((state) => {
        const blockData =
          state.blocks[id] ?? lodash.cloneDeep(state._query.data.value[id]);
        state.blocks[id] = lodash.merge(blockData, value);
      });
    },
    updateBlockField(id, path, value) {
      const state = this.$state;
      const blockData =
        state.blocks[id] ?? lodash.cloneDeep(state._query.data.value[id]);
      state.blocks[id] = lodash.set(blockData, path, value);
    },
  },
});

Or the entire query data can be cloned to the store. This would require to diff data between the store and query before it can be sent back in PATCH request, which is more direct but still viable approach that is widely used.
It makes sense to additionally cache the value of a parametrized getters/computed in a computed in a component:
const block = computed(() => store.getBlock(props.blockId));

And a writable computed is convenient to use with v-model and native elements:
const blockWidthModel = computed({
  get() {
    return block.value.dimensions.width;
  },
  set(value) {
    store.updateBlockField(props.blockId, "dimensions.width", value);
  },
});


Works like a charm ! Thanks a lot ! things are bit clearer now on the v-model subject :) I'm just need to figure out how to make the setter typesafe, since now we pass String for the path and that value can't really be validated in updateBlockField , but huge progress for now !

You're welcome. It's doable in TS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434389 , also this can be used https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/paths.d.ts . Will likely be a tad simpler to implement if "path" is an array of keys and not a string delimited with dots. IIRC there are thirdparty typesafe alternatives to lodash.set that could be used to infer the type of updateBlockField but I can't remember them
